# Is Variable Variable Possible?

Tags: php, vba, variables, variable-variables

My googlefu has failed me and I come to you for help:

Is VBA capable of having [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) like PHP? I know that in PHP you can wait to declare a variable by using `$$var`.

Is it possible to do it in VBA? for example, is there a way that lets say: I read an entire array of 1000 strings and each string that I get can declare a variable with that string, e.g if the 80th element of an array is named STO how can I tell VBA to create a variable with the name sto?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but I know that variable variables are one of those rare cases that are absolutely positively nothing but pointless and harmful. Use a freaking dictionary instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. But almost any code which relies on variable variables is horribly broken anyway and should be refactored e.g. to use array.

Edit (pst):
If you need to access values by a given name [a dictionary can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309689/hash-table-associative-array-in-vba). An excerpt/example:

```
Dim d As dictionary
Set d = New dictionary
d("STO") = arr(80) 'or whatever it is in VBA
```

Comment: So, then next question... is there Dictionary/Hash support in VBA? While it sounds like an Array/List is appropriate here, a Dictionary is a general-replacement for a "variable variables".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309689/hash-table-associative-array-in-vba

Answer (score 1):

Well you can ... sort of.

By manipulating the VBE you may add lines to your program, so defining variables as you want. Of course this is not a straightforward way, nor I recommend it. It's just for your info.

[Here is a tutorial.](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)

More examples can be found googling "VBE insertlines"

HTH!