# How do I perform a duplicate check in code?

Tags: loops

This might be a no-brainer to some, but I'm trying to check if there are any duplicate values in my code.

To be clearer, I am creating 5 variable **Integers** that randomizes a number once they are created. Let's say they're named `i1`, `i2`, `i3`, `i4`, `i5`.

I want to run a loop to check on each other to make sure they don't have any possible duplicates. If they do, I'll **re-random** the **second Integer** that's being checked. (e.g `if (i1 == i4) { i4.rand(); }`) That's to make sure `i1` doesn't need to get re-checked against all the previously checked values or being stuck in a long loop until a different number is found.

This is what I'm thinking if it was an entire if else statement : `if (i1 == i2)`, `if (i1 == i3)`, `if (i1 == i4)`, `if (i1 == i5)`, `if (i2 == i3)`, `if (i2 == i4)`, `if (i2 == i5)`, `if (i3 == i4)`, `if (i3 == i5)`, `if (i4 == i5)`

I know I can probably do it "manually" by creating lots of `if / else` statements, but is there a better way to do it? It probably isn't very feasible if I increase my Integer limit to 20 and I have to `if / else` my way through 20 value checks. I know there is, but I just can't remember. Search on Google is turning up nothing (maybe I'm searching for the wrong keywords), which is why I'm asking over here at StackOverflow.

All I want to know is how do I do it, **theory-wise** (how would you check for duplicates in theory?). The answer doesn't necessarily need to be a workable function.

If you want to create a demo code using the programming language I'm using for this problem, its`Excel VBA`. But I think this information would be able to apply theory-wise to a lot of other programming languages, so feel free to write in `javascript/jQuery`, `C++`, `C#`, etc. Just remember to comment!

Comment: I think you mean duplicate `values`, not variables. Anyway, how are you creating the random numbers to start with?

Comment: um, a random() function, provided by most programming languages -- Excel VBA has Rand().

Comment: As in, random first, then check for duplicates.

Comment: Can't thank you guys enough for opening my eyes on how to solve such a problem. I still have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for Set;

```
    Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>();
    hs.add(i1);
    if(!hs.add(i2)){
       randomize(i2);
    }
```

Hope this helps. Let me know, if you have any questions.
The above is just a concept of what to do.

To get the logic for your code, it will be

```
   Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for(int count=0; count<Array.length; count++){  // Store the data into the array and loop
        dataToInsert = Array[count]; 

        while(hs.add(dataToInsert)){
           dataToInsert = randomize(dataToInsert);
        }
     }
```

Comment: To piggy-back on this solution, you would probably want to use `do { randomize(x) } while (!hs.Add(x))` instead of the `if` block as it stands.

Comment: right, a `for` loop. So I have to put all the variables into an array first... then run the loop? Any idea what's the equivalent of .add in VBA? Or is this VBA? I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, First put the elements in the array and then loop through the array. The code above is in Java. This will work in C# too.

Comment: Link for VBA. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309689/hash-table-associative-array-in-vba

Comment: No Problem. If the answer helped you, I would appreciate if you could close the question, by accepting the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to get your integers assuming you want to generate them in the range from 1 to N

Generate an integer from 1:N
Generate an integer from 1:N-1
Generate an integer from 1:N-2
Generate an integer from 1:N-(k-1)

Now interpret these as the position of the integer that you generated (in the set of total available integers for that number) and construct your real integer.

```
Example, N = 5, k=4
3
1
2
2

i1 = 3
i2 = 1
i3 = 4 (the available integers are 2 4 5)
i4 = 5
```

Note that this requires the minimum amount of random number generations.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, what you are attempting is the wrong approach. **Theoretically**, checking for duplicates and "re-randomizing" when one is found, could execute for an infinitely long time because existing integers could continuously be chosen.

What you should be doing is constructing the collection of integers in such a way that there will be no duplicates in the first place. Dennis Jaheruddin's answer does this. Alternatively, if you have a specific set of integers to choose from (like 1-20), and you simply want them in a random *order*, you should use a [shuffling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Shuffling_algorithms). In any event, you should start by searching for existing implementations of these in your language, since it has almost certainly been done before.

Comment: I kinda realized from the fact that almost everyone's answer was based what you just wrote: "in such a way that there will be no duplicates in the first place".

Comment: @RenoYeo Actually most of them seem to have the same problem: They are   choosing a random value and checking to see if it was already chosen, which could happen any number of times before a truly unique value is chosen.

Comment: mmm. What I don't really get is Dennis' code -- a range from 1:N, lets say N is 5... so if the generator generates 4, wouldn't the next available step (1:N-1) result in a possible range of only 1 - 4 and possibly a chance to get a duplicate of what was generated in the first step?

Comment: The initial integers chosen aren't necessarily the final result. I believe the algorithm he was referring to is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12680572/933416).

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is loop over the `List<int>` and, for each element `x` at index `i`, loop while `list.Take(i-1).Contains(x)` and replace `x` with a new random number.

If you simply wanted a relatively inexpensive check that a given `List<int>` is full of unique numbers, however, you could do something like:

```
bool areAllUnique = list.Count() != list.Distinct().Count()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code:

1. Create an empty set `S`.
2. Generate a pseudo-random number `r`.
3. If `r` is in `S`, go to 2. Else, go to 4.
4. Add R to S.
5. If there are still variables to initialize, go to 2.

Exemplary implementation in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(getUniqueRandoms(5, 10));
}

public static Set<Integer> getUniqueRandoms(int howMany, int max)
{
    final Set<Integer> uniqueRandoms = new HashSet<Integer>(howMany);
    while (uniqueRandoms.size() < howMany)
    {
        uniqueRandoms.add((int) (Math.random() * max));
    }
    return uniqueRandoms;
}
```

Output:

```
[8, 2, 5, 6, 7]
```

If you would like to have them in array, not in Set, just call [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29) on your Set.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int x;
    do
    {
        x = random();
    }
    while(!set.Add(x));
}

    int i1 = set.ElementAt(0),
        i2 = set.ElementAt(1),
        i3 = set.ElementAt(2),
        i4 = set.ElementAt(3),
        i5 = set.ElementAt(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I can think of.

1: Looping over all the values in your set and comparing each one to what you're adding.

2: Creating a simplistic version of a hash map:

```
var set
var map_size
create_set(n):
    set <- array of size n of empty lists
    map_size <- n

add_number(num_to_add):
    if num_to_add not in set[num_to_add % map_size]:
        add num_to_add to set[num_to_add % map_size]
        return success
    else:
        return failure

populate_set():
    loop 5 times:
        i <- random_number()
        while(add_number(i) == failure):
            i <- random_number()
```

This way, each time you add a number, instead of checking against every other number in your set, you're only checking against at most `[max value of integer] / [map size]` values. And on average `[number of elements in set] / [map size]` (I think, correct me if I'm wrong) values.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while (list.size() < 5)
{
    int i = Math.random() * max;
    if (!list.contains(i))
    {
        list.add(i);
    }
}
```

and you'll got in `list` 5 different Integers.

Answer (score 0):

In `R` is pretty simple...

```
i <- as.integer(runif(5, 1, 10))

for(l in seq_along(i)){
  while(any(i[l]==i[-l])) # checks each against all the other
    i[l] <- as.integer(runif(1, 1, 10))
}
```

However in `R` there is the function `sample` that picks random elements from a given vector without duplicates ( even though you can choose to have them)

```
> sample(1:10, 5)
[1] 2 5 1 9 6
> sample(1:10, 5)
[1] 3 5 8 2 1
> sample(1:10, 5)
[1] 8 3 5 9 4
> sample(1:10, 5)
[1]  1  8  9 10  5
```