# VBA set an object property by name instead of index

Tags: oop, object, excel, collections, vba

I'm not sure how to ask this question so I don't know how to search for the answer. This is my first time playing with OOP and I'm in over my head as usual.

So, In VBA Excel you can reference a sheet by `index` which you can do in two ways, right?

```
Sheets (1)
    'or
Sheets ("Sheet1")
```

I am trying to do the same with my objects and collections instead of referencing an index property and I don't know where to begin. Example:

```
    Set objCar("MyCar").color = "Blue" 'from a collection of Cars
```

I'm sure I have a knowledge deficit, I'm still trying to wrap my head around whats going on with oop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309689/hash-table-associative-array-in-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost..............You use Set to create a specific instance of the object.  You can then color that instance.  Say the object is a Shape:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim S As Shape
    Set S = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    S.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(128, 0, 0)
    '
    '  Or
    '
    S.Name = "MyCar"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("MyCar").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 100, 0)
End Sub
```