# Can I use dictionaries instead of arrays even if I don't have definitions for keys?

Tags: vba

Recently I have been using the dictionary object to make arrays with unique values only by taking advantage of the `.exists` method which is simpler than writing a loop through the entire array every time to see if a value exists.  Then I get the final array by using the `.keys` method.

Given that the dictionary object requires a definition for each key, I have gone back and forth on what to set as the definition.  Originally I was setting each key's definition to the `vbempty` constant since I have no use for it anyways.  But would the best practice here be to use a `Null` value because it would take up less memory?

Comment: I think you're looking for a set, rather than a dictionary.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that.  When I google it all I get are results about the keyword `Set`

Comment: but a vba doesn't have `set` out of the box as far as I know. Maybe a custom implementation?

Comment: I'm going to look into this - but generally speaking, does `Null` take up less space than a constant 0 value?

Comment: Found a few implementations from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309689/hash-table-associative-array-in-vba

Comment: Dictionary object has a key and an item.  The key should be unique, but the item can be the same or different value for each key.

Answer (score 1):

`vbNullString` is the most efficient and should be used when you wish to assign an empty string (or when you wish to assess for an empty string).

Using `vbNullString` does not use any memory. If you're assigning `vbNullString` to a variable which previously held a value, it removes any space that was previously being used from the memory. Using `""` uses 6 bytes. Not sure how many bytes is used by `vbEmpty` or `Null`, but I always use `vbNullString`.

There is an explanation [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/microsoft.public.vb.winapi/80s4CPldxUE) and [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?351311-Why-use-vbNullString).

Comment: Interesting!  Although that 2nd link led me to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/162622) page which says: "Note that using vbNullString is equivalent to passing NULL as the parameter. This is not the same as passing an empty string ("")."  So I guess they are both the same, really!

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see/know that! So yeah, sounds like Null will do the job just as well!