# Excel Visual Basic managing coordinate tuple type

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use excel visual basic macros to automate an external program that supports API

I have created an object to interact with the API called ProgAPI and I am trying to call a function

```
ProgAPI.getcoordinate(map1, point1)
```

that would give me a coordinate in the form (x, y) which im told is a tuple

I am unable to store the coordinate in a variable when I do

```
sub getcoor
dim coor as double
coor = ProgAPI.getcoordinate(map1, point1)
end sub
```

I'm assuming because (x,y) has 2 entries

anyone know how to store this tuple in visual basic?

I tried to do and it doesnt work

```
sub getcoor
dim coor as double
coor = ProgAPI.getcoordinate(map1, point1)
end sub
```

Comment: Try just `Dim coor`   That will make it a Variant, which can store pretty much anything.  VBA has arrays: "tuple" is not a common term for VBA.

Comment: Please provide the code for ProgAPI, and in particular the code for getCoordinate.  It is difficult to help if you don't provide the appropriate code.

Comment: Some useful answers here  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196284/tuple-style-object-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

You can store a tuple as an array of two values. You can modify the code to store the coordinate as an array:

```
Sub GetCoor()
    Dim coor() As Double
    coor = ProgAPI.getcoordinate(map1, point1)
End Sub
```

In this code, the coor variable is declared as an array of type Double. When you assign the result of ProgAPI.getcoordinate(map1, point1) to coor, the two values in the tuple will be stored in the array. You can then access each value by its index, for example coor(0) for the first value and coor(1) for the second value.