# Using Dictionary Object in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to make my Dictionary object work to return economic details of selected Reference number.

e.g. I have below reference nos and corresponding values, however, not sure if I can achieve this using Dictionary object , and alternative, suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```
Ref No  Amount Price   Year
IB1232  1000   1.23    2011
IB1231  1000   3.23    2011
IB1233  1000   3.43    2011
IB1234  1000   3.43    2011
```

I thought would be able to achieve by forming Key and Value for reference and their corresponding details, but not been able to achieve ..

Comment: Are Ref No, Amount, Price, and Year seperate columns (like A:D)? What data are you trying to get back? This might be a situation where you can use VLookup (for example, if you have a reference number and you want to look it up in your data sheet and return the amount).

Comment: For dictionary structure itself in VBA, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure) SO Article.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know what you're referring to as Dictionary in VBA, as the data structure with the said functionality is called `Collection` in VBA (but maybe you coded your own Ditionary, in that case we need the code in order to be able to help you).

If I get your example right, you want to access e.g {1000,1.23,2011} via the key "IB1232". You can do this easily by creating a Collection of Collections like this:

```
Dim coll as new Collection
Dim data as new Collection

data.Add 1000
data.Add 1.23
data.Add 2011

coll.Add data, "IB1232"
```

To access your data just get the desired record (Collection) via the key

```
Debug.Print coll.Item("IB1232")(1) 'Prints 1000
Debug.Print coll.Item("IB1232")(2) 'Prints 1.23
Debug.Print coll.Item("IB1232")(3) 'Prints 2010
```

You can also use an array of Variants for the data

Comment: Hi There, thanks a lot for quick response - yes, I am refering to Dictionary object in VBA - can't I achive your example by using Dict object using Excel / VBA.

Answer (score 15):

@das_weezul

There is a Dictionary object in VBA in the scripting library (you need to add that reference to use it). The Dictionary has some extra functionality, such as the ability to check if a key exists before trying to access it.

@Sky Cobb

Yes, you could do all of the above tasks with the Dictionary. The syntax will the same, except you should provide a key for every item that you add to it.

Comment: Thans a lot managed to work with Collection - works perfectly fine and getting expeted results .

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, you need to enable a reference to get the Dictionary object, but it absolutely does exist. To add the reference: `Tools > References > [x] Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

```
Public Sub test_dict()
    Dim td As Object
    Set td = New Dictionary

    td("IB1232") = "1000   1.23    2011"
    td("IB1233") = "1000   3.43    2011"

    'Another way to do it, may be around for legacy support
    td.Item("IB1234") = "1000   3.43    2011"

    'What you probably want... a key:value dictionary where the value is a collection
    Set td("IB1231") = New Collection
    td("IB1231").add 1000
    td("IB1231").add 3.23
    td("IB1231").add 2011


    'Get value by key
    Debug.Print td("IB1234")

    'Get a collection's value.... it's 1-indexed
    Debug.Print td("IB1231")(1)

    'Test if a key exists
    Debug.Print td.exists("IB12345")

    'See how many items there are
    Debug.Print td.Count()

End Sub
```