# Scripting.Dictionary still commonly used in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I had to cobble together some code in Excel/VBA and vaguely remember we used to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime to use Dictionary. Now in the days of Office 2010, is that still the preferred way of getting access to a Dictionary like structure or have things moved on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries are still used the same old way in Excel VBA -- Read more here
[Does VBA have Dictionary Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure)

But there is an alternative to dictionary objects, using `Collections`
More about that here: [Using Dictionary Object in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834141/using-dictionary-object-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware! Microsoft Scripting Runtime does not work on Mac. 
There is a workaround though. Get this https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary
and import Dictionary.cls into your VBA project. This will create a Dictionary class that will be used instead of the one in Microsoft Scripting Runtime