# Find Worksheet Name and Row Number for an Excel Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am working with a workbook that contains three worksheets of data. Each worksheet has a Contract Number column. Certain contracts must be excluded and noted in a separate worksheet.

I would like to create Excel VBA macro that:

1. Prompts the user to enter specific contract numbers to be excluded
2. Stores contract numbers
3. Searches all three worksheets' contract column for the contract numbers
4. Notes the unwanted contract details in a "summary" worksheet, which has already been created
5. Deletes the unwanted contract row entirely

The macro should loop through this process below for 'n' number of contracts entered by the user.

```
Public contString As String
Public x As Variant
Public xCount As Variant

Sub find()
contString = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter contract numbers to exclude(Comma Delimited).      Cancel to include all contracts.", _
      Title:="Exclude Contracts", Default:="1715478")
  x = Split(contString, ",")
  xCount = UBound(x) 'Number of contracts entered by user
End Sub

Sub SearchWS1()
Sheets("WS1").Activate
Columns("I:I").Select 'Contract Number Column
Selection.find(What:=x(i), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
BKWS = ActiveCell.Worksheet.Name
BKRow = ActiveCell.Row
If BKRow > 0 Then
   Cname = Range("G" & BKRow)
   Cnumber = Range("I" & BKRow)
   Cvalue = Range("K" & BKRow)
   'Summarize Excluded Contract Info on Summary WS
   Range("Summary!B25").Value = "Exclusions:"
   Range("Summary!B26").Value = Cnumber
   Range("Summary!C26").Value = Cname
   Range("Summary!D26").Value = Cvalue
   'Select and Delete Contract
   Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
   Rows(BKRow).EntireRow.Delete
Else
   Call SearchWS2 'SearchWS2 is essentially the same as SearchWS1 and Calls SearchWS3 if contract isn't found. 
End If
End Sub
```

If the contract number doesn't exist in the first WS, I get an error like 'Object variable or With block not set'. Once I can fix this error, I will need to run this process through a loop for each contract number entered by the user. Any help with debugging the error or setting up a loop for this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can begin with VBA by recording a macro and adapt the code. Have a try and tell us where you are stuck

Comment: Hey JMax, I took a stab at it. See edits above. Any advice?

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out what you want - you meantion the user specifies x number of contracts and that you want to return (in what form?) the sheet/cell numbers that contain the contracts. But at the top you say "need to exclude". Which is it? Or is it that you want to move though out of the 3 data master sheets so that the actual work on the 3 sheets can be done?

Comment: I re-wrote the VBA code. Hopefully, it is more clear now. I appreciate Jon49's contribution, but it doesn't really solve my problem. I think there may be a simpler solution to my problem, something like the above.

Comment: AME, my code wasn't meant to solve your exact problem, if you need to change it, change it to make it work for your exact problem. My code was meant to give you a starting point. Doing it the way you do above works, it just if you have a lot of data it will go extremely slow, where my code, on the other hand, will go extremely fast (compared to what you are doing). Do as you will.

Comment: I see what you're doing now, thanks Jon49.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the `InputBox` for inputting contract numbers (let's say, comma delimited). Split the result using `Split` function.
2. Store contract numbers on a separate worksheet that you hide (`wks.visible=xlVeryHidden`, where `wks` is a `worksheet` object).
3. Find values using a multidimensional array to store the values.
4. Print 2D array to found worksheet using `rFound=saArray` (where `rFound` is a `range` object and `saArray` is the 2D array.

Make heavy use of recording macros to learn syntax.

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8350231/632495) on fast ways to retrieve and print to `cells`.

**Update:**

Sorry, this is pretty sloppy but I just threw it together and, obviously, it hasn't been tested. Hope this helps. Sorry, I also shouldn't be having you use advanced techniques like this, but it's hard for me to go back.

```
dim j as integer, k as integer, m as long, iContractColumn as integer
Dim x() as string, saResults() as string
dim vData as variant
dim wks(0 to 2) as worksheet

iContractColumn=????

set wks(0) = Worksheets("First")
set wks(1) = Worksheets("Second")
set wks(2) = Worksheets("Third")

redim saresults(1 to 100, 1 to 2)
m=0
'Loop thru worksheets
for j=0 to 2
  'Get data from worksheet
  vdata=wks(j).range(wks(j) _
    .cells(1,iContractColumn),wks(j).cells(rows.count,iContractColumn).end(xlup))
  'Loop through data
  for k=1 to ubound(vdata)
    'Loop through user criteria
    For i = 0 To UBound(x)
      'Compare user criteria to data
      if x(i)=cstr(vdata(k,1)) then
        'Capture the row and worksheet name
        m=m+1
        'If array is too small increase size
        if m>ubound(saresults) then 
          redim preserve saresults(1 to ubound(saresults)*2, 1 to 2)
        end if
        'Get name and row.
        saresults(m,1)=wks(j).name
        saresults(m, 2)=k
        exit for
      end if
    next i
  next k
next j

'Resize array to correct size
redim preserve saresults(1 to m, 1 to 2)
'Print results to a result page (you could also create hyperlinks here
'that would make it so the person can click and go to the respective page.
'You would have to do a loop for each result on the range.
with worksheets("Result Page")
  .range(.cells(1,1),.cells(m,2))=saresults
end with
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Can you help me create the 2D array based on my code above?

Comment: I updated the code with comments so you can better understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

I have little to add Jon49's answer which does seem to cover the basics.  But I wish I had discovered Forms earlier in my VBA programming career.  They can be a little confusing at first but, once mastered, they add enormously to the usability of a macro for very little effort.

Forms can be used to get values from the user (instead of InputBox) or can be used to give progress information to the user.  I will only talk about the second usage.  Your macro might take some time; has the user time to get a cup of coffee or will it finish in 5 seconds?  I HATE programs that sit there saying "please wait - this may take from a few minutes to a few hours".

The following code loads a form into memory, shows it to the user and removes it from memory at the end.  If you do not unload the form, it remains on the screen after the macro has ended which may be useful if you want to leave a message for the user.  This form is show "modeless" which means the macro displays it and carries on.  If shown "modal", the macro stops until the user has entered whatever information the form requires.

```
  Load frmProgress
  Progress.Show vbModeless
  ' Main code of macro
  Unload frmProgress
```

There are no end to the web sites offering tutorials on Forms so I will mainly describe the what rather than how.

Within the VB Editor, Insert a UserForm.  Drags the bottom and right edges if you want it bigger.  Use the Properties Window to change the Name to frmProgress.

Drag four labels from the Tool Box and arrange them in a line.  Set the caption of label 1 to "Worksheet " and the caption of label 3 to "of".  Name label 2 "lblWSNumCrnt" and name label 4 "lblWSNumTotal".

Add the following around "for j = 0 to 2"

```
frmProgress.lblWSNumTotal.Caption = 3
for j = 0 to 2
  frmProgress.lblWSNumCrnt.Caption = j + 1
  DoEvents
```

This means the user will see the following with n stepping from 1 to 3 as the macro progesses:

```
Worksheet    n  of     3
```

Add another four labels for row number, and the following code around the k loop:

```
frmProgress.lblRowNumTotal.Caption = ubound(vdata, 1)
for k = 1 to ubound(vdata, 1)
  frmProgress.lblRowNumCrnt.Caption = k
  DoEvents
```

Now the user will see something like:

```
Worksheet    2  of     3
      Row  1456 or  2450
```

The above technique is simple and does not involve any change to Jon49's code.  The following technique, borrowed from Wrox's excellent *Excel VBA Programmer's Reference*, is a little more complicated but gives your macro a more professional appearance.

Create a label that runs across the entire form.  Name it "lblToDo" and colour it white.  Create another label of the same size over the top.  Name it "lblDone" and colour it black.

Create a copy of the code to count the rows in each sheet at the top so you can calculate the total number of rows, "TotalRowsTotal", before you do anything else.

Create a new variable "TotalRowsCrnt", initialise it to zero and add one to it for every row in every worksheet.

Within the inner loop, add:

```
frmProgress.lblToDo.Width =  _
        frmProgress.lblDone.Width * TotalRowsCrnt / TotalRowsTotal
```

For Excel 2003, which all the organisations I work with still use, this gives a progress bar with the black Done label steadily covering the white ToDo label.  Later version of Excel may offer a progress bar control as standard.

I hope this gives you some ideas for making your macros more attractive to your users.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent advice. A progress bar is definitely appropriate for the macro I'm working on. It's posts like yours that make me a huge fan of SO!