# How should I Notify the user during a long process?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some long processes that require notifications to the user at successive stages, so that he doesn't get to believe `Excel` has crashed down.

How could I display asynchronous messages to the user in `Excel`, using `VBA` ?

Comment: I use Forms for displaying progress information.  [See my answer to this question][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360981/find-worksheet-name-and-row-number-for-an-excel-workbook/8367240#8367240

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has suggested, I would suggest changing the cursor during execution: Application.Cursor = xlWait

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the status bar in Excel to do this:

```
Application.StatusBar = "status message"
```

Here is an example on how to implement this: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=87

Below is the code from the site (added line break to make is easier to read):

```
Sub StatusBar()

Dim x As Integer
Dim MyTimer As Double

'Change this loop as needed.
For x = 1 To 250
    'Dummy Loop here just to waste time.
    'Replace this loop with your actual code.
    MyTimer = Timer
    Do
        Loop While Timer - MyTimer < 0.03
        Application.StatusBar = _
        "Progress: " & x & " of 250: " & Format(x / 250, "Percent")
    DoEvents
Next x

Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**:
I do want to add that updating the status bar will result in a sizable hit in performance (quite a bit actually), so you should only update it in approriate intervals. Here's an example of what I mean (I use MOD here to ensure we only increment each 1000):

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim temp As String

For i = 1 To 1000000
    temp = "testing 123, testing 123"
    If i Mod 1000 = 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & i & "/1,000,000..."
    End If
Next

Application.StatusBar = "Ready"

End Sub
```

Also note that you want to reset the text to "Ready" otherwise it'll be left as if it were in the loop.

Comment: Not many people actually take notice of the status bar, though... It's easy to overlook. But if you know it's there and expect it to be displaying useful information, this is a good way to go.

Comment: Yeah, another way is you can go through the trouble of making a windows form that displays the status. But if someone is using a file that has a hefty macro, they should be aware of the status bar, or made aware of it somehow.

Comment: It is true also that some people might not expect the status bar to be "application related". They might be used to Excel printing generic things in there, no ?

Comment: @TomJuergens: ok, so just make the user aware of it initially with `MsgBox "Follow progress in the Statusbar below."`.

Comment: A fine suggestion, Jean-Francois. And I'd like to add that Excel uses the status bar and no one is that confused when they do something that takes time and Excel 'freezes' as it works on it (if anything that makes your eyes look for something moving on the screen).

Comment: +1 I really like the status bar suggestion, it's inocuous and already expected behavior from Excel. I do wish that more people would look at it, especially when it says "Calculate" and they wonder why their formulas are coming out with wrong results.

Answer (score 4):

I've stuck with [Walkenbach's progress form](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/site/tip/displaying_a_progress_indicator/) for my addins

[image]

Comment: Looks cool and safe. However, I am using three screens, as well as my users most of the time. At the moment,when I download the example, the pop up gets printed sometimes on a different screen that the one having the active Excel. Any idea how to fix that since you know the piece quite well ?

Comment: @jeromeG When you say three screens, do you mean you have 3 files open in one instance of Excel spread over three screens? Or 3 separate instances of Excel running?

Comment: I mean that I have 3 physical screens, and one Excel instance open on one screen. What is funny is that when I open VBE, the popup will always appear on the screen on which VBE is displayed. If I move VBE to another screen, the popup will appear there the next time. The screen on which Excel is doesn't affect anything. Once I close VBE, the popup continues to get displayed on the last screen on which VBE was. Well the issue is, when the actual Excel is on the screen on the left, I don't want the popup to come up two screens away from it :D

Answer (score 2):

The following article has a number of ways of doing this: http://oreilly.com/pub/h/2607

I think the best bet for you would be to show a progress form. This can include a progress bar and text updates to reassure the user.

Answer (score 1):

Something I once did was to create an extra tab called "Running".
After each time consuming loop, I add the following code with updated text information.

Although the text sometimes changes too fast, the changing color bar shows the user that the script is still running. You have to define AlertColor first with a value of 6.

```
Sheets("Running").Select 'Show the running page

Range("B18").Value = "Importing ABC......"

Cells(18, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = AlertColour

AlertColour = AlertColour + 1

If AlertColour > 8 Then AlertColour = 6

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how far you want to go with your solution, but you can utilise [RTD function](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289150). That way you could put a status message directly in the worksheet. But it would require development of a COM Automation server, which is not complicated (can be written in .NET or VB6 or C++ or Delphi), but causes problems once in production (deployment, support, code control etc.)