# Is there any limitation for IF condition while using "OR" in vb?

Tags: vba, vb6, vbscript

In my code i want to use if condition. In which i want to use "OR" around 18 times.
Like for e.g.

```
If a="something" or a="something" or a="something" or.........(up to 18 times)... then
  'do nothing
else
  'do action
end if
```

[Note : value of **a** is changing in **For loop** every time]
so i just want to ask does there any limitation in IF for using OR in limited times.
OR is there any other better way to do the same.

Thanks

Comment: I was having the same problem. After two "ands" I was getting the property or method error. After I used Case for my 10 <> conditions in my looping for loop and it worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no limitation when using `OR` this way.

Yet, you may consider alternative ways of coding this.

#### Negating a condition using Not

First, if you `do nothing` in the first case, then consider **using the `Not` statement**:

```
If Not True Then
'do somethin
'no else
End If
```

#### Consider using Select Case

Second, if you are checking the very same variable, you could either consider **using a `Select Case`** but it doesn't seem appropriate in your case if you have only one case.

#### Try to use a search

Eventually, if you are checking strings, you could probably better use a **search within an array** (with `Application.Match` if you are within Excel or [`.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eefw3xsy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) or **within a String** using [`Instr`](http://www.automateexcel.com/2004/08/14/excel_vba_find_text_in_a_string_instr/).

#### Using a collection or a dictionary

[EDIT] Another very good way to handle this would be to use the **[Dictionary Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure) of VBA** and check if `a` exists (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164502%28v=office.10%29.aspx) for some information).

Comment: Looks like a canidate for Select Case to me...`a` is the variable getting tested against over and over again.

Comment: @tcarvin: That's why I pointed out it existed. Yet, `Select Case` is very useful when you have many `Else If` (i.e. several cases) whereas you have a single outcome here so I would consider using other solutions (array, dictionary...).

Comment: And for String comparisons a Like operator or even regex matching might be a cleaner option depending on what is being tested for.

Comment: In general: if you have to ask for the limitation of a system, then probably there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is just an elaboration on my comments to JMay, full credit to him.  I think the original poster meant to the "Something" in his question differ, with `a` being the loop variable.

```
For each a in MyList

   Select Case a
   Case "something", "something2", "something3", "something4", "something5", _
        "something6", "something7", "something8", "something9", "something10", _
        "something11", "something12", "something13", "something14", "something15", _
        "something16", "something17", "something18"

       'DO NOTHING

   Case Else

       'do-something code goes here
       ' and here
       ' and here
       ' and here
   End Select

Next a
```

Comment: nicely done. I wasn't familiar enough to the `Case` syntax and I didn't remember you could use the comma as an `OR` operator :)

Comment: @JMax Well, then you'll appreciate the [Select Case True](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbscript-select-case-statement-complete.html) construct even more. It can also be used for [short circuit evalution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).