# Access or Excel best tool for the job

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Need some advice, I have a large excel sheet that I need to break up by a value in column B. The kicker is in some cases i need more then one value from column B. Example I might want A and B together and C on its own.  I have another workbook that has this mapping. I'm stuck on 1 Best tool for this job and 2 how.

In Excel im not sure how to make this work. I know i'll need a loop to go through the list, but how do i handle the ones that need to be combined?

In access I was thinking a table for the data and a table for my package list. The create a query and loop the values into the query using VBA.

Comment: Where is the data *now*? Where does the data *need* to be? What is the *scope* of the entire project?

Comment: The data is in an excel workbook. In the end the data needs to be in excel. The scope of the project is to take a large data set that is in excel break it out based on the value in column in B, taking the data and putting it into new workbooks. Save the files with a name that is from the package workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to break your main sheet to multiple sheets based on value in column B.

You can make use of excel vba dictionary

[Does VBA have Dictionary Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure)

1. You need to load the workbook that has the mapping into the dictionary as below:

   Key = 'value in column B'

   Value = 'name of the sheet where you want that data to go'
2. Loop through the sheet containing the data get the value in column B, lookup in the dictionary to get the sheet name to which this data should go. Write the data into that sheet name.

Hope this helps.