# Remove duplicate values from rows

Tags: csv, google-sheets, sublimetext3

I have a Google Sheet with 100 rows and 2 columns.

The first column is a 2 letter code -  `AA`, `AB`, `AC` and so on. Each code has a corresponding series of comma separated values in the second column.

I want to remove duplicates from the comma separated values in the second column

[image]

I'm happy to do this within Google Sheets or download the values and use SublimeText or similar.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082680/remove-duplicate-cells-in-a-row), but the proposed solution isn't compatible with Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",",TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(B2,",")))))))
```

Drag fill down

Comment: Thanks - if I paste this over the first value in column B, I get a circular dependency error. 

If I paste it in the empty cell above the first value, it works, but when I drag down it updates all cells with the lowermost value it affects (if that makes sense).

Comment: Paste it in C column. In C1 copy and paste..And drag fill down.