# Excel VBA Dealing with 64 values for one argument

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a VBA script I'm trying to run that reads incoming emails to an account and then marks the corresponding cell in a spreadsheet. My test run had 9 jobs it was looking for in a Nested IF Statement.

Like this:

```
  If InStr(itm.subject, "Test Backup") > 0 Then 
    J = 2
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TESTdchq") > 0 Then 
        J = 3
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TESTdynamics") > 0 Then 
        J = 4
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TEST-VSS-HQ") > 0 Then 
        J = 5
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TESTWSUS01") > 0 Then 
        J = 6
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TEST-Camera") > 0 Then 
        J = 7
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TEST-Vcenter") > 0 Then 
        J = 8
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TEST-View Connection") > 0 Then 
        J = 9
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TESTktsrv1") > 0 Then 
        J = 10
  End If
```

However one of my practical applications has 64 jobs. I need a more efficient way to assign the value to J based on the keyword in the subject of the email. Id assume I could do something with an array and then call the array and compare to the subject.

Here is the whole test script if that helps.

```vba
Sub ReconcileTest(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
  Dim ExcelWkBk As Excel.Workbook
  Dim FileName As String
  Dim PathName As String
  Dim J As Integer
  'J = will be used to declare the proper Job row

  PathName = "C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\Backups\"
  FileName = "TESTReconcileSheet.xlsx"
  'Declare J
  If InStr(itm.subject, "Test Backup") > 0 Then 
    J = 2
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TESTdchq") > 0 Then 
        J = 3
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TESTdynamics") > 0 Then 
        J = 4
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TEST-VSS-HQ") > 0 Then 
        J = 5
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TESTWSUS01") > 0 Then 
        J = 6
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TEST-Camera") > 0 Then 
        J = 7
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TEST-Vcenter") > 0 Then 
        J = 8
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TEST-View Connection") > 0 Then 
        J = 9
    ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "TESTktsrv1") > 0 Then 
        J = 10
  End If

  Set xlApp = Application.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  With xlApp
    .Visible = True         ' Visible is used for debugging
    Set ExcelWkBk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(PathName & FileName)
    With ExcelWkBk

      'VBA code to update workbook here
      Dim todaysDate As Date
      Dim D As Integer    
      Dim subject As String
      'D = will be used to declare the proper Date column

      todaysDate = Day(Now)
      D = todaysDate
      'Marksheet
      If InStr(itm.subject, "[Success]") > 0 Then
      .Sheets("sheet1").Cells(J, (D + 2)).Value = "S"
      .Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(J, (D + 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
      ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "[Failed]") > 0 Then
      .Sheets("sheet1").Cells(J, (D + 2)).Value = "F"
      .Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(J, (D + 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      ElseIf InStr(itm.subject, "[Warning]") > 0 Then
      .Sheets("sheet1").Cells(J, (D + 2)).Value = "W"
      .Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(J, (D + 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
      End If

      .Save
      .Close
    End With
    .Quit
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: 1 Step better would be using [Select Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) so that your only evaluating `itm.subject` once. 2 steps better might be an array but I think your best bet is to use a [dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure) for this.

Comment: Use a lookup table on a worksheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using a dictionary for such a large number of variables.  You can create a global dictionary if necessary but the following example is done locally:

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dict.Add "Test Backup", 2
dict.Add "TESTdchq", 3
dict.Add "TESTdynamics", 4
dict.Add "TEST-VSS-HQ", 5
dict.Add "TESTWSUS01", 6
dict.Add "TEST-Camera", 7
dict.Add "TEST-Vcenter", 8
dict.Add "TEST-View Connection", 9
dict.Add "TESTktsrv1", 10

Dim J As Integer
J = dict(itm.Subject)

MsgBox "J = " & J
```

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! for the response, I'll try that now.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I think it gets me very close to where I need to be. However the script is currently not pulling The J variable out of the subject properly. To clarify the email subjects are in the following format "Test Backup [Success] completed at 2:30 11/4/2014." 

I'm not sure if Dictionary is by default looking for a keyword, or if I need to use Instr() for that?

Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: That's going to be a little more difficult with a dictionary. Is the string always in the same format in terms of the key is always followed by a space and `[`?  If yes, try this: `J = dict(Trim(Split(itm.subject, "[")(0)))`

Comment: Yes the subject format for every job is: %jobname% [%status%] %timestamp% %date%

Comment: Man, I wish I had two more rep so I could up vote your answers! that did the trick.

Comment: Given that the subject is variable but has structure, what about storing Regex objects in the dictionary and matching against the subjects?

Comment: Blackhawk, I'm not very familiar with REgex objects in VBA. any resource you'd recommend I could read up on them with?

Comment: Here is a helpful [link about Excel VBA Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops/22542835#22542835) that I put together that gives several common examples.