# VBA map implementation

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, collections

I need good map class implementation in VBA.
This is my implementation for integer key

Box class:

```
Private key As Long 'Key, only positive digit
Private value As String 'Value, only 

'Value getter
Public Function GetValue() As String
    GetValue = value
End Function

'Value setter
Public Function setValue(pValue As String)
    value = pValue
End Function

'Ket setter
Public Function setKey(pKey As Long)
    Key = pKey
End Function

'Key getter
Public Function GetKey() As Long
    GetKey = Key
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()

End Sub
```

Map class:

```
Private boxCollection As Collection

'Init
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set boxCollection = New Collection
End Sub

'Destroy
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set boxCollection = Nothing
End Sub

'Add element(Box) to collection
Public Function Add(Key As Long, value As String)
    If (Key > 0) And (containsKey(Key) Is Nothing) Then
    Dim aBox As New Box
    With aBox
       .setKey (Key)
       .setValue (value)
    End With
    boxCollection.Add aBox
    Else
       MsgBox ("В словаре уже содержится элемент с ключем " + CStr(Key))
    End If
End Function

'Get key by value or -1
Public Function GetKey(value As String) As Long
    Dim gkBox As Box
    Set gkBox = containsValue(value)
    If gkBox Is Nothing Then
        GetKey = -1
    Else
        GetKey = gkBox.GetKey
    End If
End Function

'Get value by key or message
Public Function GetValue(Key As Long) As String
    Dim gvBox As Box
    Set gvBox = containsKey(Key)
    If gvBox Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Key " + CStr(Key) + " dont exist")
    Else
        GetValue = gvBox.GetValue
    End If
End Function

'Remove element from collection
Public Function Remove(Key As Long)
    Dim index As Long
    index = getIndex(Key)
    If index > 0 Then
        boxCollection.Remove (index)
    End If
End Function


'Get count of element in collection
Public Function GetCount() As Long
    GetCount = boxCollection.Count
End Function

'Get object by key
Private Function containsKey(Key As Long) As Box
    If boxCollection.Count > 0 Then
           Dim i As Long
           For i = 1 To boxCollection.Count
             Dim fBox As Box
             Set fBox = boxCollection.Item(i)
             If fBox.GetKey = Key Then Set containsKey = fBox
          Next i
       End If
End Function

'Get object by value
Private Function containsValue(value As String) As Box
       If boxCollection.Count > 0 Then
           Dim i As Long
           For i = 1 To boxCollection.Count
             Dim fBox As Box
             Set fBox = boxCollection.Item(i)
             If fBox.GetValue = value Then Set containsValue = fBox
          Next i
       End If
End Function

'Get element index by key
Private Function getIndex(Key As Long) As Long
    getIndex = -1
    If boxCollection.Count > 0 Then
           For i = 1 To boxCollection.Count
             Dim fBox As Box
             Set fBox = boxCollection.Item(i)
             If fBox.GetKey = Key Then getIndex = i
          Next i
       End If
End Function
```

All ok if i insert 1000 pairs key-value. But if 50000, a program freezes.

How i can solve this problem? Or maybe there more better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main problem with your implementation is that the operation `containsKey` is quite expensive ([O(n) complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions)) and it is called at every insert and it never breaks even when it "knows" what would be the result.

This might help a little:

```
...
If fBox.GetKey = Key Then
    Set containsKey = fBox
    Exit Function
End If
...
```

In order to reduce the `containsKey` complexity typical things to do would be

- keep the keys sorted so that you can use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) instead of linear search
- keep the keys in tree or in a [hashed buckets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

The most straightforward thing to do would be using the `Collection`'s built-in (hopefully optimized) ability to store/retrieve items by a key.

Store:

```
...
boxCollection.Add Item := aBox, Key := CStr(Key)
...
```

Retrieve (not tested, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305733/2626313)):

```
Private Function containsKey(Key As Long) As Box
    On Error GoTo err
        Set containsKey = boxCollection.Item(CStr(Key))
        Exit Function
    err:
        Set containsKey = Nothing
End Function
```

See also:

- [MSDN: How to: Add, Delete, and Retrieve Items of a Collection (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f26wd2e5(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Stack Overflow: Does VBA have Dictionary Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure)
- [Newton Excel Bach: Arrays vs Collections vs Dictionary Objects (and Dictionary help)](http://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/arrays-vs-collections-vs-dictionary-objects-and-dictionary-help/)