# VBA ArrayList Of Arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, arraylist

I have a list of 2 columns that A has a random number associated with it and B has a string item. So i was thinking I could make any Arraylist of arrays, but i would like to make the name of the Array the number so it can quickly be referenced.  I've tried

```
Dim row As Integer
Dim arrList As Object
Dim arr As Variant

arrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

row = 1
While Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & row))
ReDim arr(0 To 1) As String
arr(0) = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & row)
arr(1) = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row)
arrList.Add (arr)

row = row + 1
Wend
```

Is there a quick way to search ArrList(arr(0)?

Comment: You can't programmatically name a variable. It has to be a literal string declared at compile time

Comment: So is there any other way of doint this other than adding A, and B to a single array. then adding that array to arrayList?  And calling on arr(0) to look at A column.

Comment: When you say "arrayList" are you referring to an array of arrays - or an actual "arrayList" object?

Comment: an Arraylist object ill edit my code to reflect what ive changed it to.

Comment: my only problem is.  I need a way to see if arrList contains a specific number.  I dont think i can do that like i have it right now because ill have to look at each arr(0) to see taht

Comment: It looks like you want the data structure known as a Map, which in general in the Microsoft world is referred to as a Dictionary. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure) for more

Comment: mk to use one (had to look this up) but i would create a dictionary then .Add "Pizza", 1000.  How would i search for the 1000 part. Ive never learned about dictionary's before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should be using the Dictionary object (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187234) and ([Does VBA have Dictionary Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure)).

You can use `.Exists` to check if your key/item exists in the Dictionary or not.

```
Dim dctMyList As Dictionary
Dim nCount As Integer
Dim sKey As String

Set dctMyList = New Dictionary

For nCount = 1 To 5
  sKey = "Fruit_" & nCount
  dctMyList.Add sKey, Choose(nCount, "Apple", "Banana", "Date", "Fig", "Pear")
Next nCount

If dctMyList.Exists("Fruit_2") Then
  Debug.Print dctMyList.Items(1)
Else
  ' Do something else
End If
```

Note that you can use `.Items` to access the contents, which is a zero-based index. So in the above example, "Banana" is the second item added to the Dictionary, but has an index of 1.

Comment: Awesome thank you.  So i made 2 dictionaries because i have 2 different sets of data.   I use the .Exists it works, but I would like to use the Keys() fuction instead of looking for the item it tells me to it goes to the index.  For example one of my items i wanna look for is 1002, which is actually index 2, When i search for 1002 it takes me to the key in index 1002. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve... Using `Dict.Keys` will return an Array of all the Key values in the Dictionary. Are you trying to get an Item from it's Key? or a Key for an Item? I suspect you are trying to get a specific Item out of the Dictionary based on it's Key value. In which case you want `Dict.Item(YourKeyValue)`. So in my above example, `Debug.Print dctMyList.Item("Fruit_5")` would return "Pear". n.b. `.Item` and `.Items` are different and do different things.

Comment: Sorry.  Im trying to get a Key value from its Item, But my items are integer.  So when i do .Keys(activesheet.range("A" & x)) it returns the key at index "A"x instead of the key at item "A"x.

Comment: It sounds like you are not really understanding the Dictionary object and I'm struggling to make sense of what you're actually trying to do. If you're trying to get a Key from it's Item, then it sounds like you've loaded your Dictionary the wrong way round! i.e. your Keys are used to help find your Items. If not, then you cannot directly get a Key from an Item (items may not be unique), but instead you can loop through all the Keys looking for one with a matching Item: 
`For Each sMyStringKey In dctMyDict.Keys()
    Range("A" & sMyStringKey).Value = dctMyDict.Item(sMyStringKey)
Next`

Comment: Also see this: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/660596-scripting-dictionary-exits-keys-items-etc.html