# Random selection of cells without duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I found a function for selecting random cells but it returns also duplicates.

```
Function RandomSelection(aRng As Range)
    'Update20131113
    Dim index As Integer
    Randomize
    index = Int(aRng.Count * Rnd + 1)
    RandomSelection = aRng.Cells(index).Value
End Function
```

I need the function to do similar but without duplicates.

Comment: *'Random selection of cells without duplicates'* is an oxymoron. Nothing is random is there are conditions attached.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a *UDF()* that returns an **array**:

```
Public Function NoRepeats(inpt As Range) As Variant
   Dim ary(), nItems As Long, i As Long
   Dim r As Range
   nItems = inpt.Count
   ReDim ary(1 To nItems)

   i = 1
   For Each r In inpt
      ary(i) = r.Value
      i = i + 1
   Next r

   Call Shuffle(ary)

   ReDim temp(1 To nItems, 1 To 1)
   For i = 1 To nItems
      temp(i, 1) = ary(i)
   Next i

   NoRepeats = temp

End Function


Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim HowMany As Long, i As Long, J As Long
    Dim tempF As Double, temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For i = Low To Hi
        Helper(i) = Rnd
    Next i

    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - J
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = tempF
            temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = tempF
            temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = temp
          End If
        Next i
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

This has been coded to returns the results in ***column*** format, *(see the dimming of `temp` in the UDF)*

[image]

Note that the UDF() has been entered in array fashion  with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: I inserted the function and I get #Name error

Comment: @Emanuel  make sure all the code is in a **standard module.**

Comment: It still returns duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You could store each RandomSelection in a dictionary

[Does VBA have Dictionary Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure)

and then before setting RandomSelection check the dictionary (Dictionary.exists(value)) to see if the value you are about to set it to has been used before.