# Excel vba Variant array lookup

Tags: vba, excel, variants

I have two (non empty) arrays (of variants) with numbers. I would like to list all the data that is in the first array and is not in the second array.

```
Dim existingWorkerIDs() As Variant
Dim newWorkerIDs() As Variant

  For Each temp In newWorkerIDs

        If existingWorkerIDs.contains(temp) Then
            ...do sth...
        End If

   Next temp
```

Is it possible?

Comment: it might be simpler to use a dictionary.  Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily doable by abusing `MATCH`.

The first procedure is just a test for verification, and also an example of how things have to be declared (and conversely, what declarations you would have to change if you need other variable types, etc).

```
Sub testCaller()
    Dim testArr1() As Variant ' <~~ Variable type must match
    Dim testArr2() As Variant '     the variable required in the 
    Dim testArr3() As Variant '     actual procedure
    Dim testArr4() As Variant


    testArr1 = Array("abc", "abc", "def", "abc", "asdf", "bcd")
    testArr2 = Array("abc", "asdf")
    Call listUniqueArrayContents(testArr1(), testArr2())

    testArr3 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    testArr4 = Array(1, 2)
    Call listUniqueArrayContents(testArr3(), testArr4())
End Sub

Sub listUniqueArrayContents(arr() As Variant, arrCompare() As Variant)
    Dim uniqueValues() As Variant
    Dim mIndex As Variant
    Dim j As Integer

    j = 0

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr())
        ' Reset the placeholder for our MATCH values
        mIndex = Null

        ' Disable errors, otherwise you get popups every time there's a unique value
        On Error Resume Next

        ' Call MATCH function
        mIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.match(arr(i), arrCompare(), 0)

        ' Restore normal error handling
        On Error GoTo 0

        If mIndex < 1 Or IsNull(mIndex) Then
            ' If match variable is Null, it means the value was unique
            ' So we'll write that value to a separate array to keep track of it
            If j = 0 Then ReDim Preserve uniqueValues(0 To 0)
            If j <> 0 Then ReDim Preserve uniqueValues(UBound(uniqueValues()) + 1)
            uniqueValues(UBound(uniqueValues)) = arr(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Debug.Print "--Unique values:--"
    For k = LBound(uniqueValues()) To UBound(uniqueValues())
        Debug.Print uniqueValues(k)
    Next k
    Debug.Print "--End--"
End Sub
```

Which, for the test examples, gives you the expected:

> --Unique values:--
>   def
>   bcd
>   --End--
>   --Unique values:--
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   --End--

Alternatively, you can change this into a `Function` and have it return the array of unique values.

Change this:
`Sub listUniqueArrayContents(arr() As Variant, arrCompare() As Variant)`

to this:
`Function listUniqueArrayContents(arr() As Variant, arrCompare() As Variant) As Variant`

and replace the last-most `For`-loop with `listUniqueArrayContents = uniqueValues()`