# VBA, Advanced Filter & Remove Duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list full of different paths in col A. 
I have a list of details in B and C.

How can I on a new sheet:   1)  pull each unique path,   2) for each path compile the values from B * C and remove the duplicates. 3) repeat the next path after these are done in the latest row.

I do have a faulty macro, but for the sake of being concise and accurate I will not post. Unless someone wants to read it, please reques

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is what I have(I understand its long, i'll take try to clean it up abit) :**

```
Sub FileDetail()
'Does not fill down, go to bottom to unleased fill down
'Skips unreadable files
'This Macro retrieves data from files picked. The data is based on header. Data is also filtered for unique values.
'You must make sure headers are in the first row and delimted.


Dim wb As Workbook, fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet, wksSummary As Worksheet
    Dim y As Range, intRow As Long, i As Integer

Dim r As Range, lr As Long, myrg As Range, z As Range
    Dim boolWritten As Boolean, lngNextRow As Long
    Dim intColNode As Integer, intColScenario As Integer
    Dim intColNext As Integer, lngStartRow As Long
    Dim lngLastNode As Long, lngLastScen As Long
    Dim intColinstrument As Integer, lngLastinstrument As Long



   'Skipped worksheet for file names
   Dim wksSkipped As Worksheet
   Set wksSkipped = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skipped")


     ' Turn off screen updating and automatic calculation
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

     ' Create a new worksheet, if required
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unique data")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
        Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
        wksSummary.Name = "Unique data"
    End If

     ' Set the initial output range, and assign column headers
    With wksSummary
        Set y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Set r = y.Offset(0, 1)
        Set z = y.Offset(0, -2)
        lngStartRow = y.Row
        .Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("File Name", "Sheet Name", "Node", "Book", "Instrument")
    End With

'get user input for files to search
Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
If errCheck Then
   Exit Sub
End If
'''
For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary




On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wb = Nothing    ' or set a boolean error flag
End If
On Error GoTo 0    ' or your custom error handler

If wb Is Nothing Then
wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = fileNames(Key)

Else
    Debug.Print "Successfully loaded " & fileNames(Key)
    wb.Application.Visible = False 'make it not visible
    ' more working with wb




 ' Check each sheet in turn
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
             ' Only action the sheet if it's not the 'Unique data' sheet
            If .Name <> wksSummary.Name Then
                boolWritten = False



       ''''''''''''''''''testing additional column..trouble here



                                 ' Find the Anchor Date
                intColScenario = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                intColScenario = WorksheetFunction.Match("instrument.instrumentType", .Rows(1), 0)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If intColScenario > 0 Then
                     ' Only action if there is data in column E
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(intColScenario)) > 1 Then
                       lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intColScenario).End(xlUp).Row


                         ' Copy unique values from the formula column to the 'Unique data' sheet, and write sheet & file details
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColScenario), .Cells(lr, intColScenario)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , r, True
                        r.Offset(0, -2).Value = ws.Name
                        r.Offset(0, -3).Value = ws.Parent.Name



                         ' Delete the column header copied to the list
                        r.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                        boolWritten = True
                    End If
                End If

          ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''below is working'''''''''''''''''''''''

                 ' Find the Desk column
                intColNode = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                intColNode = WorksheetFunction.Match("book.reportingLine.pathName", .Rows(1), 0)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If intColNode > 0 Then
                     ' Only action if there is data in column A
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(intColNode)) > 1 Then
                        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intColNode).End(xlUp).Row

                         ' Copy unique values from column A to the 'Unique data' sheet, and write sheet & file details (if not already written)
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColNode), .Cells(lr, intColNode)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , y, True
                        If Not boolWritten Then
                            y.Offset(0, -1).Value = ws.Name
                            y.Offset(0, -2).Value = ws.Parent.Name
                        End If

                         ' Delete the column header copied to the list
                        y.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    End If
                End If

          ' Find the Intrument
                intColinstrument = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                intColinstrument = WorksheetFunction.Match("instrument.instrumentType", .Rows(1), 0)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If intColinstrument > 0 Then
                     ' Only action if there is data in column A
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(intColinstrument)) > 1 Then
                        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intColinstrument).End(xlUp).Row

                         ' Copy unique values from column A to the 'Unique data' sheet, and write sheet & file details (if not already written)
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColinstrument), .Cells(lr, intColinstrument)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , z, True
                        If Not boolWritten Then
                            z.Offset(0, -3).Value = ws.Name
                            z.Offset(0, -4).Value = ws.Parent.Name
                        End If

                         ' Delete the column header copied to the list
                        z.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    End If
                End If




         ' Identify the next row, based on the most rows used in columns C & D
                lngLastNode = wksSummary.Cells(wksSummary.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
                lngLastScen = wksSummary.Cells(wksSummary.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
                lngLastinstrument = wksSummary.Cells(wksSummary.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
                lngNextRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(lngLastNode, lngLastScen) + 1

                If (lngNextRow - lngStartRow) > 1 Then

                   ' Fill down the workbook and sheet names
                    z.Resize(lngNextRow - lngStartRow, 2).FillDown


                    ''''''''Optional if you want headers to be filled down.

                    'If (lngNextRow - lngLastNode) > 1 Then


                         ' Fill down the last Node value
                        'wksSummary.Range(wksSummary.Cells(lngLastNode, 3), wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow - 1, 3)).FillDown
                    'End If
                    'If (lngNextRow - lngLastScen) > 1 Then
                         ' Fill down the last Scenario value
                        'wksSummary.Range(wksSummary.Cells(lngLastScen, 4), wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow - 1, 4)).FillDown
                    'End If


                End If



                Set y = wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow, 3)
                Set r = y.Offset(0, 1)
                Set z = y.Offset(0, -2)
                lngStartRow = y.Row
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
wb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the workbook do not save
Set wb = Nothing 'release the object
End If

Next 'End of the fileNames loop
Set fileNames = Nothing

 ' Autofit column widths of the report
wksSummary.Range("A1:E1").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Reset system settings
With Application
   .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Visible = True
End With
End Sub
```

So this code gets file name, sheet name, and columns I specify's data.

1)  However I am having trouble adding additional columns to this. (I currently get 2 extracted columns), and also

2) I am having trouble putting it in a format where it columns are based upon each other. ex It will give me unique value for each path, but then not the unique values per sport.

Edit to include data ( I also would like to include a 4th and 5th column but kept it to 3 for simplicity):

```
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| path                          | sport      | Teams        |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/larrybird     | basketball | celtics      |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/michaeljordan | basketball | bulls        |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/tigerwoods    | golf       | pga          |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/josebautista  | baseball   | bluejays     |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/jordanspeith  | golf       | pga          |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/kevinlove     | basketball | timberwolves |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/lebronjames   | basketball | cavs         |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/stephencurry  | basketball | warriors     |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/larrybird     | baseball   | redsox       |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/michaeljordan | baseball   | whitesox     |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/michaeljordan | chess      | knight       |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/michaeljordan | basketball | hornets      |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/kevinlove     | basketball | cavs         |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/tigerwoods    | golf       | pga          |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
```

And expected result (I included fill down in this)

```
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| path                          | sport      | teams        |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/larrybird     | basketball | celtics      |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
|                               | baseball   | red sox      |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/tigerwoods    | golf       | pga          |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/michaeljordan | basketball | bulls        |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
|                               |            | hornets      |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
|                               | baseball   | whitesox     |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
|                               | chess      | knight       |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/kevinlove     | basketball | timberwolves |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
|                               |            | cavs         |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| stack/over/flow/josebautista  | baseball   | bluejays     |
+-------------------------------+------------+--------------+
```

It seems to be an issue for the 3rd (4th and 5th also) columns with getting unique values.

Comment: for getting an answer (and any help at all) you should always show what you have tried so far... it also does help us in helping you :)

Comment: @DirkReichel, Posting now. Mind you its long lol. :(

Comment: That doesn't matter... (everything is better than nothing) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind having the results sorted, instead of in the original order, the following code will do that.  It should "auto-adapt" to any number of columns.

*(If you need the results in the original order, I would use Collections or Dictionaries and User Defined Object approach)*

Your data should start in `A1` (with Row 1 being the column labels) and you can see where, in the code, you define the Worksheets for your Source and Results data.

Since most of the "work" is done within a VBA array, rather than on the worksheet, it should run quite rapidly.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub SortFormat()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vRes As Variant
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

'Set source and results worksheets, ranges
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    wsRes.Cells.Clear
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Copy source data to results worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
With wsSrc
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    R.Copy rRes
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

'Go to Results sheet
With wsRes
    .Select
    .UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
rRes.Select

'Sort the data
With wsRes.Sort.SortFields
    .Clear
    Set R = wsRes.UsedRange.Columns
    For Each C In R
        .Add Key:=C, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    Next C
End With

With wsRes.Sort
    .SetRange R
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .Apply
End With

'Remove any completely duplicated rows
'Create array of columns
ReDim V(0 To R.Columns.Count - 1)
For I = 0 To UBound(V)
    V(I) = I + 1
Next I

R.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(V), Header:=xlYes

'Remove Duplicated items in each row
'Work in VBA array for more speed
vRes = R

For I = UBound(vRes, 1) To 3 Step -1
    If vRes(I, 1) = vRes(I - 1, 1) Then vRes(I, 1) = ""
    For J = 2 To UBound(vRes, 2)
        If vRes(I, J) = vRes(I - 1, J) And _
            vRes(I, J - 1) = "" Then vRes(I, J) = ""
    Next J
Next I

R = vRes

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The easy way would be, to copy the whole range, sort it and then run some calculations:

```
Sub Macro1()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim str As String
  With Sheet1
      str = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), .Cells(1, 3)).Address
      .Range(str).Copy Sheet2.Cells(1, 1)
  End With
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  With Sheet2
    .Activate
    Dim str2 As String
    str2 = .Range(str).Offset(1).Resize(.Range(str).Rows.Count - 1).Address
    .Range(str2).Value = Evaluate("if(" & str2 & "="""",-1E+99," & str2 & ")")
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add .Range(str).Offset(1).Resize(, 1), 0, 1, , 0
    .Sort.SortFields.Add .Range(str).Offset(1, 1).Resize(, 1), 0, 1, , 0
    .Sort.SortFields.Add .Range(str).Offset(1, 2).Resize(, 1), 0, 1, , 0
    .Sort.SetRange .Range(str).Offset(1)
    .Sort.Header = 2
    .Sort.Apply
    .Range(str2).Value = Evaluate("if(" & str2 & "=-1E+99,""""," & str2 & ")")
    Dim val As Variant, i As Long, rng2 As Range
    val = .Range(str).Value
    Set rng2 = .Range(str).Offset(.Range(str).Rows.Count).Resize(1)
    For i = 3 To UBound(val)
      If val(i - 1, 1) = val(i, 1) And val(i - 1, 2) = val(i, 2) And val(i - 1, 3) = val(i, 3) Then Set rng2 = Union(rng2, .Range(str).Rows(i))
    Next
    i = .Range(str).Rows.Count - rng2.Rows.Count
    rng2.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    With .Range(str).Offset(1).Resize(i - 1, 1)
      .Value = Evaluate("if(" & .Address & "=" & .Offset(-1).Address & ",""""," & .Address & ")")
      With .Offset(, 1)
        .Value = Evaluate("if((" & .Address & "=" & .Offset(-1).Address & ")*(" & .Offset(, -1).Address & "=""""),""""," & .Address & ")")
      End With
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

*Done by phone, may contain errors!*
*Changed a lot now, please copy the whole code and test it again.*

**EDIT**

Ok, a completely different solution. Should be fast, but may not be very clear in the way it works :P

```
Sub Macro2()

  Dim inVal As Variant, outVal() As Variant, orderArr() As Variant
  Dim startRng As Range
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, iCount As Long

  Set startRng = Sheet1.Range("A2:C2") 'upmost row-range of the range to be copied (exclude headers!)
  With startRng.Parent
    inVal = .Range(startRng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, startRng.Column).End(xlUp)).Value
  End With
  ReDim orderArr(1 To UBound(inVal))
  For i = 1 To UBound(inVal)
    iCount = 1
    For j = 1 To UBound(inVal)
      For k = 1 To UBound(inVal, 2)
        If StrComp(inVal(i, k), inVal(j, k), 1) = 1 Then iCount = iCount + 1
        If StrComp(inVal(i, k), inVal(j, k), 1) <> 0 Then Exit For
      Next
    Next
    orderArr(i) = iCount
  Next
  k = 1
  ReDim outVal(1 To UBound(inVal, 2), 1 To UBound(inVal))
  For i = 0 To Application.Max(orderArr)
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(i, orderArr, 0)) Then
      iCount = Application.Match(i, orderArr, 0)
      For j = 1 To UBound(inVal, 2)
        outVal(j, k) = inVal(iCount, j)
      Next
      k = k + 1
    End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve outVal(1 To UBound(inVal, 2), 1 To k - 1)
  For i = 1 To UBound(outVal)
    For j = UBound(outVal, 2) To 2 Step -1
      If outVal(i, j - 1) = outVal(i, j) Then
        If i = 1 Then
          outVal(i, j) = ""
        ElseIf outVal(i - 1, j) = "" Then
          outVal(i, j) = ""
        End If
      End If
    Next
  Next
  'upper left cell of the output-range
  Sheet2.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(outVal, 2), UBound(outVal)).Value = Application.Transpose(outVal)
End Sub
```

Feel free to set the starting range (`Sheet1.Range("A2:C2")`) to `Selection` and then simply select the range and start the macro. Does work with any size (while VERY big ranges may freeze excel for some time).

As always: if you have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for the reply, its really good. What if I wanted the unique values in the 3rd column? It seems to repeat the values over.  Also this doesnt give all the values from the 3rd column.

Comment: There is still an unwanted behavior: if {a,b,c} is followed by {a,b, } then the second line will be empty and will also not deleted (can't be avoided the way sorting works). You would need to also check for such rows and delete them too.

Comment: get an error on, `Set rng2 = Union(rng2, Rng.Rows(i))` object required .

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I am getting an error on `Rng.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp`, going to restart my laptop its slow.

Comment: Changed that too... I should not try to do stuff like that always via "brain" :P

Comment: Thanks Dirk, Seems like I am still not getting the full filtered column 3 results. Column b works great, just not the 3rd one.

Comment: Never mind I think the column 3 results are correct. Sorry :P . But I still am getting duplicates in the 3rd col.

Comment: Thank u for satifying my needs! How would I add additional column to be extracted? is it easy? or does it mess it all up?

Comment: Also to add, seems like all values do not show for the 3rd column. I have no clue why. Sorry to be such a bother. There may be more values in col 3 then 2 and 1.

Comment: @Jonnyboi added a different solution... please check if any errors pop up or the output is not as desired

Comment: Works really good :) , I just have to much data and it runs slow :( , so maybe ill have to shorten the data.

Comment: @DirkReichel has a much better solution. Glad someone could help. Sorry that I took you on a goose chase.

Answer (score 2):

One efficient solution would be to:

- Fisrt copy the values with `Range.Copy`
- Then sort the rows with `Range.Sort`
- Then remove the duplicated rows with `Range.RemoveDuplicates`
- Finally remove the duplicated branches with a loop

This procedure removes the duplicated rows and format as a tree view:

```vb
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim rgSource As Range, rgTarget As Range, data(), r&, c&

    ' define the source, the target and the number of columns
    Const columnCount = 3
    Set rgSource = Range("Sheet1!A3")
    Set rgTarget = Range("Sheet1!F3")

    ' copy the values to the targeted range
    Set rgSource = rgSource.Resize(rgSource.End(xlDown).Row - rgSource.Row + 1, columnCount)
    Set rgTarget = rgTarget.Resize(rgSource.Rows.Count, columnCount)
    rgSource.Copy rgTarget

    ' sort the rows on each column
    For c = columnCount To 1 Step -1
      rgTarget.Sort rgTarget.Columns(c)
    Next

    ' build the array of columns for RemoveDuplicates
    Dim rdColumns(0 To columnCount - 1)
    For c = 1 To columnCount: rdColumns(c - 1) = c: Next

    ' remove the duplicated rows
    rgTarget.RemoveDuplicates rdColumns
    Set rgTarget = rgTarget.Resize(rgTarget.End(xlDown).Row - rgTarget.Row + 1, columnCount)

    ' format as a tree view by removing the duplicated branches
    data = rgTarget.Value
    For r = UBound(data) To 2 Step -1
      For c = 1 To columnCount - 1
        If data(r, c) <> data(r - 1, c) Then Exit For
        data(r, c) = Empty
      Next
    Next
    rgTarget.Value = data

End Sub
```

Comment: I like that solution. Use `RemoveDuplicates VBA.Array(1, 2, 3)` to evade possible problems with `option base 1`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This works amazing however I am getting many duplicates of all 3 columns. Is there a way to just do the unique path, unique teams, and unique sport. I get many duplicates of each.

Comment: @Jonnyboi, I fixed the procedure (just had to iterates backwards instead of forward to remove the duplicated branches). I tested it with your example and get the same result.

Comment: Awesome Florent. I have duplicates in the last col, am I missing something? Unique values in col B is fine, C not sure why.

Comment: I pasted the data. Are the values in col C just filled down ? I dont mind this view aslong as the other values are filled down(your current code; For pivot table I can see this being useful). But also don't mind the view we are discussing where it shows just unique values.

Comment: @Jonnyboi, found the issue. the `RemoveDuplicates` was not applied to the full range. I added a line to resize the targeted range to the number of rows.

Comment: Cool :) , how do I add additional criteria (extra columns to be included), is it a  large work around?

Comment: I've updated the example. You can define the number of columns in `columnCount`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a unique list of anything, use a [Dictionary object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure).

Make sure to add a reference to the Scripting Runtime controls! Just some quick and dirty code (as in completely untested) based on your sample data:

```
Sub GetUniques()
    Dim oDic as New Dictionary
    Dim r as Integer
    Dim strKey as String
    Dim varValue(2) as Variant

    'Get a unique list of Column A values
    r = 3 'Your data starts on row 3
    Do While Cells(r,1).value <> "" 'Run until the first blank line
        strKey = Cells(r,1).value 
        varValue(0) = Cells(r,2).Value
        varValue(1) = Cells(r,3).Value
        If Not oDic.Exists(strKey) Then 
            oDic.Add strKey, varValue
        End If
        r = r +1
    Loop

    'Now display your list of unique values
    Dim K as Variant
    Dim myArray as Variant
    r = 3 'We'll start on row 3 again but move over to column I (9)
    For Each K in oDic.Keys
        Cells(r,9).Value = K
        myArray = oDic.Item(K)
        Cells(r,10).Value = myArray(0)
        Cells(r,11).Value = myArray(1)
        r = r + 1
    Next K

End Sub
```

Comment: `oDic.Add strKey, varValue` the key is already associated with an element of this collection

Comment: Sorry, made a small typo on the line above it. This: `If Not oDic.Exists(key) Then` should be this: `If Not oDic.Exists(strKey) Then`

Comment: Hi Tim, works really well actually. One problem though is the 3rd column, is it not listing all the values that pertain to that path, it is missing a few.

Comment: Doh! This is totally a stupid error on my part. :( It is only checking column A for uniqueness. So if you have two rows: {1, 2, 3} and {1, 2, 2}, it does not recognize that they are different because it only checks A, not all 3. The quick fix would be to concatenate all 3 cells into one string and use that as the key for the dictionary, then increase the array to 3 elements and store columns A, B, and C. I'll modify the code again.

Comment: Fuuuu! That won't work either. Lemme think about this for a bit.

Comment: @Jonnyboi Is there ever a case where one row is an exact duplicate of another row? For example, is it possible that row `stack/over/flow/larrybird : basketball : celtics` appears more than once? Or will every row *always* be unique? EG, once JordanSpeith : Golf appears, it *never* appears again.

Comment: HI Tim,  yes I believe there will be rows with exact duplicates.