# It is possible to have an array with no upper bound?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm populating an array based on whether or not criteria across a worksheet are met. The thing is, I don't know how long the array is, as it could be larger than the dataset itself (will have duplicates of some entries). What I have is something along the lines of:

```vb
Sub ArrayTest
Dim MyArray as Variant
Dim i as Long
Dim index as Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
ReDim myarray(index)

For i = 1 to lastrow
    If (something) then
        index = index  + 1
        ReDim Preserve recordArrray(Index)
        recordArrray(Index) = range("A" & i)

    End If 
Next
End Sub
```

However, once `index` reaches `lastrow`, I get a `subscript out of range` error. I can avoid this by simply replacing the `ReDim` line with `ReDim myarray(1 to 100000000).` Obviously, this is not an ideal solution.

Can I create an array without having to define what the upper bound will be before it is created?

Comment: You always have to define the upper bound.  Alternatives would be to `Redim Preserve` every so often, perhaps in sizes of 1000, or to use a Collection (or Dictionary).

Comment: If you don't want do redim the array too often, maybe a [dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure) is what you're looking for. In your example the index shouldn't get higher than lastrow though and using an upper bound and redimming after the loop might be more efficient. edit: there is also an example for a collection in the linked question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays always have to have both an upper and lower bound (though you can change the boundaries dynamically with `Redim`).

My guess is that the problem you're running into is that **the starting value for index is 0** which is outside of the legal bounds of your array. I suspect that this would fix the immediate problem:

```vb
Sub ArrayTest
Dim MyArray as Variant
Dim i as Long
dim index as Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
ReDim myarray(1 to lastrow)

For i = 1 to lastrow
    If (something) then
        index = index  + 1
        recordArrray(Index) = range("A" & i)
    End If 
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Redimming in the loop worked. I've updated the original question now.