# Counting unique text values and making dynamic dashboard in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, distinct-values

[image]

I have a reference file for a dashboard I am making. I want to be able to count the unique org names in a reference file column and make that number the amount of column headers in my separate dashboard. I used macro recorder to make it unique, but I am unsure of how to translate this into making a dynamic number of columns for my dashboard based on the count of unique org names in the ref file. Here's a picture attachment example of what the reference file could look like. So, if it counts that there are 5 unique names, I would like the separate dashboard to make 5 columns with those names as headers in each column.

```
  Sub Macro1()


 '     Macro1 Macro

Columns("F:F").Select
Range("F1:F10000000000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,  CopyToRange:=Columns _
    ("O:O"), Unique:=True

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ROWS(R[-11]C:R[-2]C)"

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it by loading the unique results into an array. This assumes the column headers go into A1.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim wsRef As Worksheet
Dim wsDB As Worksheet

Set wsRef = Worksheets("reference")
Set wsDB = Worksheets("Dashboard")

With wsRef
    .Range("C1:C9").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("F1"), Unique:=True

    Dim arrValues As Variant
    arrValues = .Range("F2", .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

End With

With wsDB
    .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(1, UBound(arrValues))).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrValues)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this works! the column headers will start at row F and loop every other row..any way to do that instead of every row at A1?

Comment: change `A` to `F` and add a counter to step 2 for the row number in the cell reference.

Comment: for step 2 do you add a for loop?

Comment: @beks123 - probably, but its hard to say without seeing you construct. research it. if you get stuck, post another question and someone will help you figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Dictionary object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure?s=9|2.8455) to get your unique values, then loop through the dictionary items to make your column headers. eg,

```
myCol = 1
For Each item in oDic.items
    'Presuming you want your headers to start at A1
    Cells(1, myCol).Value = item
    myCol = myCol + 1
Next
```