# Finding a string in a time range

Tags: excel, vba

How could I highlight a duplicate part number within a time range, of the same date, or the next day.

```
 1qwerty      2017-02-28
 2qwerty      2017-02-26
 3qwerty      2017-02-21
 4qwerty      2017-02-21
 4qwerty      2017-02-21
 5qwerty      2017-02-21
 2qwerty      2017-02-20
 3qwerty      2017-02-20
 5qwerty      2017-02-20
 6qwerty      2017-02-19
```

So in this instance, the 5th, 8th and 9th line would be highlighted as these are within the same day or on the next day of the part number being searched for. 
I would need to create a loop that would do this for each line, potentially 100 rows.

Here is some more data, ive put in what works as being highlighted and where it has not worked as Should be higlighted, thanks

```
 2017-02-27 1qwerty   Highlighted
 2017-02-27 2qwerty 
 2017-02-27 1qwerty 
 2017-02-27 3qwerty 
 2017-02-27 4qwerty 
 2017-02-27 5qwerty 
 2017-02-27 6qwerty 
 2017-02-24 5qwerty 
 2017-02-23 14qwerty    
 2017-02-23 15qwerty    
 2017-02-23 16qwerty    
 2017-02-23 14qwerty   Highlighted
 2017-02-22 17qwerty    
 2017-02-22 1qwerty 
 2017-02-21 14qwerty    
 2017-02-21 19qwerty    
 2017-02-20 6qwerty 
 2017-02-20 20qwerty    
 2017-02-20 21qwerty    
 2017-02-20 19qwerty   Highlighted
 2017-02-20 1qwerty 
 2017-02-17 5qwerty 
 2017-02-17 14qwerty    
 2017-02-17 1qwerty 
 2017-02-17 22qwerty    
 2017-02-17 23qwerty    
 2017-02-17 1qwerty   Should be Highlighted
 2017-02-17 19qwerty    
 2017-02-17 1qwerty   Should be Highlighted
 2017-02-16 24qwerty    
 2017-02-16 25qwerty    
 2017-02-16 26qwerty    
 2017-02-16 27qwerty    
 2017-02-16 28qwerty       
 2017-02-16 1qwerty    
 2017-02-16 24qwerty   Highlighted
 2017-02-16 29qwerty    
 2017-02-15 1qwerty 
 2017-02-07 6qwerty   Should be Highlighted
 2017-02-07 6qwerty     
 2017-02-07 30qwerty    
 2017-02-07 31qwerty    
 2017-02-07 19qwerty    
 2017-02-07 32qwerty    
 2017-02-06 6qwerty 
 2017-02-01 33qwerty    
 2017-02-01 33qwerty   Should be Highlighted
 2017-02-01 34qwerty
```

Any help is much appreciated as always!

Comment: what is your question, are you asking here how to do a loop, rather than searching?

Comment: If you're open to having a helper column you could just use the following formula which will highlight any duplicates: `=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A1,$B$1:B1,B1)>=2,"Duplicate","")`

Comment: Nathan_Sav- I'm not sure how it would work, thats why i wrote down writing in a loop, in case it might be used.

Comment: Jordan Does this find a duplicate in both columns. I have tried this formula , it only brings up the 5th row as a duplicate. Now its the questions of creating a formula that has the next day included.

Comment: Perhaps try: `=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A1,$B$1:B1,B1-1)+COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A1,$B$1:B1,B1)>1,"Duplicate","")`

Comment: Thanks for additional formula Jordan.   This also brings up the same 5th row being a duplicate. Question, for the logical test, what does the (<=2, >1) mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not a hard task if you keep your dates in order (ascending or descending) and if you don't - just sort with order first!

So let's bind to descending order like in your data example! My **input** in that case looks like this:

[image: input]

Note, that in my example I use dictionary object to track items, that I searched for.

> To use a dictionary object you need reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime!

**Example routine**:

```
Option Explicit


Sub Test()
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim DataDict As Dictionary
    Dim RawData As Variant

    Dim CurrentSearch As Range
    Dim TestPrevSearch As Range
    Dim FirstSearch As Range

    Dim CurrentDate As Date

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Dim DebMsg As String

    Set WS = ActiveSheet                                   'or whatever sheet your want
    Set DataDict = New Dictionary                          'setting-up a dictionary

    With WS
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set DataRange = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    End With

    RawData = Application.Transpose(DataRange)             'transposing raw data

    If Not IsArray(RawData) Then _
            Exit Sub

    'iterating over each qwerties
    For i = LBound(RawData) To UBound(RawData)
        Debug.Print "Search for " & RawData(i)

        If Not DataDict.Exists(RawData(i)) Then
            'Get first search
            Set TestPrevSearch = Nothing
            Set CurrentSearch = DataRange.Find(What:=RawData(i), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not CurrentSearch Is Nothing Then

                'Maybe it's a bug - but sometimes it's start search from second occurence...
                Set TestPrevSearch = DataRange.FindPrevious(After:=CurrentSearch)
                If Not TestPrevSearch Is Nothing Then
                    If TestPrevSearch.Row < CurrentSearch.Row Then
                        Debug.Print "Bug search fixed......"
                        Set CurrentSearch = TestPrevSearch
                    End If
                End If

                CurrentDate = CurrentSearch.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value
                Debug.Print vbTab & "Found in  " & CurrentSearch.Address & vbTab & vbTab & "Date is " & CurrentDate _
                        & vbTab & vbTab & "Reference date"

                Call DataDict.Add(Key:=RawData(i), Item:=CurrentDate)

                Set FirstSearch = CurrentSearch
                Do
                    'Get next search in loop
                    Set CurrentSearch = DataRange.FindNext(After:=CurrentSearch)

                    If Not CurrentSearch Is Nothing Then
                        If CurrentSearch.Address = FirstSearch.Address Then
                            Exit Do
                        Else
                            CurrentDate = CurrentSearch.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value

                            DebMsg = vbTab & "Found in " & CurrentSearch.Address & vbTab & vbTab & "Date is " & CurrentDate


                            'If CurrentDate older then date in a dict
                            If CurrentDate < DataDict(RawData(i)) Then

                                'Check if it was yesterday (if you need to check for tomorrow - get rid off "-" sign)
                                If CurrentDate = DateAdd("d", -1, DataDict(RawData(i))) Then
                                    CurrentSearch.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                                    DebMsg = DebMsg & vbTab & vbTab & "Highlighted (Yesterday to reference)"
                                    'If it even older...
                                Else
                                    DataDict(RawData(i)) = CurrentDate
                                    DebMsg = DebMsg & vbTab & vbTab & "New Reference (Older then reference)"
                                End If

                                'If Dates are equal
                            ElseIf CurrentDate = DataDict(RawData(i)) Then
                                CurrentSearch.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                                DebMsg = DebMsg & vbTab & vbTab & "Highlighted (Equal to reference)"
                                'Rewrite date in dictionary if younger
                            Else
                                DataDict(RawData(i)) = CurrentDate
                                DebMsg = DebMsg & vbTab & vbTab & "New Reference (Younger then reference)"
                            End If
                            Debug.Print DebMsg
                        End If
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print vbTab & "already found"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

**Output**:

[image: output]  [image: output]  [image: output]

**Bonus output** (check your immediate):

[image: bonusoutput]

*It would help if you gonna edit my logic!*

**Summary**:

1. Iterating over `qwerty` entries instead of 100 lines is noticeably faster!
2. We need (not really, but it's easier with sorted data) to sort our data first!

**Useful links**:

[Does vba have dictionary structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure)

[.Find and .FindNext in Excel VBA](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

[Find last row, column or last cell](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

Comment: Yes, this is great thanks!  The data is sorted so thats easy also. I'm going to look through the code if i need to make any alterations.

Comment: Also when i have tried this on my data, its coming up with an error on For i=LBound to UBound. Run time error 13, type mismatch. Is this because i have filters in my data.

Comment: @J Junior, Glad if it works like you desired! To deal with error 13 try to check `If IsArray(RawData)` and iterate if true. I didn't give enough time to possible errors, leaving error handling and optimisation to you.

Comment: Oh yeh thats fine by me, :)  I've just copy and pasted the data into a new worksheet, I've just tested it with a range of 100 rows. but only works for about 20 rows, then it doesn't work, to do the rest. But when i paste in a section of data at a time of 20 rows it works great? any ideas

Comment: So what if i had, 3qwerty 01,01,2017 then 3qwerty 01,01,2017, then 4qwerty 02,01,2017 then 3qwerty 02,01,2017. How i would i highlight the two 3qwerties. As they are duplicates from the first 3qwerty. but still within today and next day.

Comment: @JJunior, if you need help, can you update your question with more data so i can play with it?

Comment: @J Junior, And I updated my answer. There was a little bug with logic (reference date doesn't renew if older then yesterday), so I fixed this and added a bonus output to immediate window so now you can track flow of routine and fix logic by yourself (since our outputs are little bit mismatched again, but i think that my is good)!

Comment: This is great dude, thank you very much!! I do like the immediate window part nice to know whats going on.