# How to SelectRow of a Task in Sub-Project (inside a Master-Project)

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a Master-Project, and inside it I have several Sub-Projects.

I want to format the Color of the Rows based on a value of a field `Text5`.

**Current Problem**: How to use VBA code to refer to the Row in the 2nd Sub-Project.
When I run the code, and I modify `Text5` value in Task ID 5 (in Sub-Project 2), it modifies the color of Task ID 5, but of Sub-Project 1.

How can I use the `SelectRow` and add refference to the desired Sub-Project ?

***My Code*** (relevant section)

```
Sub FormatChangedTasks()

Dim SubPrj      As Subproject
Dim Tsk         As Task
Dim i           As Long

For Each SubPrj In ActiveProject.Subprojects
    ' compare the name of Sub-Project with the one saved in the "Stack" srray
    If SubPrj.SourceProject.Name = ModifiedPrjName Then
        For Each Tsk In SubPrj.SourceProject.Tasks
            If Not Tsk Is Nothing Then
                i = Tsk.ID

                ' check if Tsk.Text5 value has changed from value in "StatusStackArr" array
                If StatusStackArr(i - 1).StatusOldVal <> Tsk.Text5 Then
                    ' **** at the line below it selects the Row from the top
                    ' (not the desired Sub-Project) ******
                    SelectRow Row:=i, RowRelative:=False

                    ' --format entire row --
                    Select Case Tsk.Text5 ' Get the Field's used field, not name
                        Case "R", "Y", "G"
                            FontEx CellColor:=7, Color:=0
                            FontEx Italic:=False '  Font regular

                        Case "Complete"
                            FontEx Italic:=True '  Font Italic
                            FontEx CellColor:=15, Color:=14 ' Background Silver ; font Gray

                    End Select

               ' rest of code (un-relevant)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Challenge—Formatting a row in a master project

To format text in a table, use the [FontEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Project-VBA/articles/application-fontex-method-project) method. This method formats the active (selected) cells. To select a row for formatting, use the [SelectRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-selectrow-method-project) method. To use this method you need to know:

1. Its position relative to the active selection, or
2. Its absolute position within the **visible tasks**, or
3. Find the task based on a unique identifier

For both options 1 and 2 tasks hidden by filters or collapsed summaries mean that the row parameter for the `SelectRow` method must be adjusted accordingly. It is very difficult to know which tasks might be hidden. The best way to use this method is to first make sure that all tasks are visible (see code).

Additionally, when working with subprojects, it is a challenge to calculate the absolute row position as first you need to get the task count of subprojects higher up in the schedule plus any native tasks in the master project itself (although this is atypical).

All of this leads to using the `Find` method, **option 3, as the best way to select a task within a master project**. To select exactly the correct task, then Find method must be used with a unique field. The Unique ID field is the only field guaranteed to be unique.

### Unique IDs within a master project

When tasks are added to a project, an incremental Unique ID is assigned, starting with 1. When projects are combined within a master project, the Unique IDs are changed by adding a seed value so that there are no duplicates within the master project.

The seed value is based on an internal, subproject "index". The first subproject's tasks are given a seed value of 4194304, the second subproject's tasks have a seed value of 8388608 (4194304 * 2), and so forth.

If a subproject is removed from the master, it's "index" is not re-used. Similarly, if subprojects are rearranged in the master, the "index" values do not change. Therefore, you cannot use the `Index` property of the subproject object to obtain the internal "index" value that is used to create the seed as that property simply indicates the order of subprojects.
(Note, there is a way to get this internal value, but that's beyond the scope of this question. FYI it also requires selecting all tasks.)

### Solution

To select a task in the user interface, you'll need to know it's Unique ID in the master schedule. If you access the task by way the `SourceProject.Tasks` method you'll be accessing the tasks in their native subproject and the Unique ID will not include the seed value. For example, the Unique ID will be 2 which is not unique within the master project and therefore not sufficient to select the task with the Find method.

Since you are already looping through all the tasks in the schedule, the easiest way to determine the master Unique ID is to loop through the tasks natively in the master project. To do that select all tasks and loop through the selection.

```
Sub FormatChangedTasks()

' show all tasks
FilterClear
SelectAll
SummaryTasksShow (0)
OutlineShowAllTasks

Dim AllTasks As Tasks
Set AllTasks = ActiveSelection.Tasks

Dim Tsk As Task

For Each Tsk In AllTasks
    If Not Tsk Is Nothing Then
        ' compare the name of Sub-Project with the one saved in the "Stack" srray
        If Tsk.Project = ModifiedPrjName Then

            ' check if Tsk.Text5 value has changed from prior value
            ' NOTE: use a dictionary here instead of an array
            If StatusStackArr(i - 1).StatusOldVal <> Tsk.Text5 Then

                Find "Unique ID", "equals", Tsk.UniqueID
                SelectRow

                ' --format entire row --
                Select Case Tsk.Text5 ' Get the Field's used field, not name
                    Case "R", "Y", "G"
                        FontEx CellColor:=7, Color:=0
                        FontEx Italic:=False '  Font regular

                    Case "Complete"
                        FontEx Italic:=True '  Font Italic
                        FontEx CellColor:=15, Color:=14 ' Background Silver ; font Gray

                End Select

            ' rest of code (un-relevant)
        End If
    End If
Next Tsk
End Sub
```

Notes:

- Selecting all tasks is a requirement unless you can guarantee that the schedule is already fully expanded and you go with option 1 or 2. Selecting all tasks will take a little time with 10-15 subprojects, but the rest of the code will run at close to the same speed.
- All bets are off with option 1 or 2 if tasks are grouped or otherwise not sorted by task ID.
- Storing the previous values in an array indexed by task ID will not work well with a master project. Instead, store the previous values in a collection or dictionary with the master Unique ID as the key. [See this SO post about using dictionaries in VBA.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is there a way to use the Find "unique ID" method and afterwards go to that row without looping through selection, I don't like the selecting all tasks, it will slow down the code runtime , and shows bad on the screen. The master project will have sometime 10-15 sub projects, so it will slow down the code runtime a lot. I wanted to loop only through the modified task's sub-project. Is there such a way ?

Comment: @ShaiRado see edits above for an explanation of why selecting all tasks is all but inevitable and why it's really not bad. It may seem like a hack, like a bad Excel macro, but it's not, especially since the alternatives are either both very constrained or difficult to implement, or both.

Comment: thanks for an amazing detailed answer. I have already started to calculate the number of lines per sub projects, and some nice math. However, I will try your solution tomorrow (Israel time) and see if the response time is acceptable. If you are still awake, the "master unique ID" is it the same as Task.UniqueID? Or there is another property?

Comment: BTW, is there a way to format a task's row background color without using SelectRow? (Like in Excel VBA)

Comment: @ShaiRado There is not a separate Unique ID field; the task's Unique ID is different when viewed in a master project. For example, when looking at a task within a master, the Unique ID might be 8388611, but if you open that subproject directly, the Task Unique ID would be 3 (8388611 mod 4194304).

Comment: @ShaiRado Regarding cell formatting, the methods all work on the active selection. So no, it's not like Excel, unfortunately.

Comment: You are most likely of to bed, I'm not able to get the UniqueID saved corretly. I'll post a new one, not to confuse future users on this site