# Range of cell rows to column base on first row values in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have range of cells in excel like

```
A   A   A   B   B   B
A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3
```

Is there any idea how to convert this range of cell into -

```
A   B
A1  B1
A2  B2
A3  B3
```

I tried to do it with Kutools addon in excel but it can't solve my problem.
I don't mind if I have to use VBA for this.

Comment: Is this a one-off or does it need to be automated and presented to a user as a turnkey operation?

Comment: this is just one-off, doesn't need to present to user

Comment: This looks like a typical example of a dictionary usage. Can you give it a try? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure

Comment: Thank for pointing this @Vityata but it still looks complicated for me. I am not that strong with VBA :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula in cell `A7`. Enter it with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER combination, then drag below your table.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$F$2,2,SMALL(IF((A$6=$A$1:$F$1), COLUMN($A$1:$F$1)-MIN(COLUMN($A$1:$F$1))+1, ""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @Kresimir L.. The formula solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have managed to do, using dictionaries. I am using the following additional functions:

This one loops through the values in the first row and returns the unique ones as array. It will be the "title" of the list:

```
Public Function getUniqueElementsFromArray(elementsInput As Variant) As Variant

    Dim returnArray     As Variant
    Dim element         As Variant
    Dim tempDict        As Object
    Dim cnt             As Long

    Set tempDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each element In elementsInput
        tempDict(element) = 1
    Next element

    ReDim returnArray(tempDict.Count - 1)
    For cnt = 0 To tempDict.Count - 1
        returnArray(cnt) = tempDict.Keys()(cnt)
    Next cnt

    getUniqueElementsFromArray = returnArray

End Function
```

This one gets the lastRow of a given column:

```
Function lastRow(Optional strSheet As String, Optional colToCheck As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim shSheet  As Worksheet

    If strSheet = vbNullString Then
        Set shSheet = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set shSheet = Worksheets(strSheet)
    End If

    lastRow = shSheet.Cells(shSheet.Rows.Count, colToCheck).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

This one takes a single row range and returns a 1D array:

```
Public Function getArrayFromHorizontRange(rngRange As Range) As Variant

    With Application
        getArrayFromHorizontRange = .Transpose(.Transpose(rngRange))
    End With

End Function
```

This is the main "engine":

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim keyValues       As Variant
    Dim keyElement      As Variant
    Dim keyElementCell  As Range
    Dim inputRange      As Range
    Dim outputRange     As Range
    Dim outputRangeRow  As Range
    Dim colNeeded       As Long

    Set inputRange = Range("A1:K2")
    Set outputRange = Range("A10")
    Set outputRangeRow = outputRange

    keyValues = getUniqueElementsFromArray(getArrayFromHorizontRange(inputRange.Rows(1)))

    For Each keyElement In keyValues
        Set outputRangeRow = Union(outputRangeRow, outputRange)
        outputRange.value = keyElement
        Set outputRange = outputRange.Offset(0, 1)
    Next keyElement

    For Each keyElementCell In inputRange.Rows(2).Cells
        colNeeded = WorksheetFunction.match(keyElementCell.Offset(-1), outputRangeRow, 0)
        Set outputRange = Cells(lastRow(colToCheck:=colNeeded) + 1, colNeeded)
        outputRange.value = keyElementCell
    Next keyElementCell

End Sub
```

And this is the input and the output:
[image]

Comment: that's amazing!