# How to store and sort data from a csv file into a dictionary VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, csv, dictionary

I am relatively new to VBA and I have a project where I need to sort data from a big .csv file containing a whole year's information of a parking lot by month.

The csv file contains only three parameters.

**- UNIX timestamp** which indicates the time a car entered/left the parking lot.

**- userID** that identificates the person who entered/left the park.

**- IN/OUT tag** that informs if said person entered/left the park at that given timestamp.

After storing the file in an array and printing it, it looks like this.

[image: (Just a small fragment from the first few entries)]

My goal is to sort these entries by month of occurence, creating a new Excel sheet for each month, but most importantly, in each new sheet the format needs to be:

**- Unique Event ID** - A random unique ID that identifies this specific event. (has to be different from each event ID from another sheet)

**- userID** - Same as the one described above

**- Timestamp of IN** - The timestamp of when the user entered the park

**- Timestamp of OUT** - The timestamp of when the user left the park.

After sorting everything, each monthly sheet should look something like this:

[image]

Here is the part of my code that reads each line from the file (where I need help)

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
numLines = 0

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, Line
    elements = Split(Line, ";")

    'Store in an array
    someArray(numLines, 0) = elements(0)
    someArray(numLines, 1) = elements(1)
    someArray(numLines, 2) = elements(2)

    'ts - elements(0)
    'uID - elements(1)
    'evID - elements(2)

    'I'm trying store the data in a dictionary with the IN timestamp as
    'the key and the userID as the item but I still can't figure out
    'how to look for the next timestamp of the user and store it so I could
    'print it in another sheet

    'dict.Add elements(0), elements(1)
    'Debug.Print elements(0), dict(elements(0))

    numLines = numLines + 1
Loop
Close #1

Range("A1:C" & totalFileLines).value = someArray
```

I've come across dictionaries and found that it could be my a good solution but I've had no success with it so feel free to suggest whatever seems like a more simpler way to solve this because, as I said, I'm still fairly new to VBA and I'm having a really hard time with this part of my project so any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Read in the entire file in one step, perhaps using the `FileSystemObject`.  Use `Split` function to put it into an array. If you don't have long-term stays, you can probably just use a loop to go down the few rows until `OUT`.  If you do, it might be more efficient to set up a dictionary (at least at first), with UserID as the key and have the items be a dictionary of IN's and matching OUT's with their associated times

Comment: Look at this post for excel vba dictionary object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure

Comment: Can you not convert csv to xlsm via code (or import from csv)> turn data into pivot with month in page field > then use showPages method which will chuck every month into its own sheet (not sure if you have more than one year's data). Wasn't sure about your comment on ids across pages but you could loop the relevant column in all relevant pages and use a counter variable to add your new unique id if required. That can all be done easily with very little vba code.

Comment: You should also look at Powerquery as being suitable for this sort of task

Comment: @RonRosenfeld But from what I understand the dictionary keys must be unique and my .csv file can have the same userID coming IN and OUT of the parking lot several times throughout the whole year. Also I still don't understand how can I find the value of the corresponding OUT timestamp and store it in the user's dictionary. Could you please elaborate a bit more on your answer? It would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance for taking your time to help me

Comment: That's why, for each dictionary item with key for `User 1`, you would have, as the stored item, another Dictionary or Collection (or Array) with the IN/OUT times for that user.

Comment: As pointed out by @QHarr, this can also be done using PowerQuery.  Not sure which learning curve would be shorter.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld If its not asking too much, could you write that specific part of the code you just described in the read file function? It is really confusing to me as I am trying to reproduce what you said in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your question in the comment about reading the file, something like below:

*Note that I am using early-binding (set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime), but you could also use late binding, especially if the code will be distributed.*

```
    Dim V
    Dim fn As Variant
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, TS As TextStream

fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files(*.csv),*.csv")

If fn = False Then Exit Sub

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(fn, ForReading, False, TristateUseDefault)

V = Split(TS.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
```

`V` will now contain a zero-based array where each element consists of one line/row from the `csv` file.

### Edit

In response to your question about storing the information in the Dictionary object, if you change your code to:

```
    If Not dict.Exists(elements(1)) Then
        Set collec = New Collection
        collec.Add elements(0)
        dict.Add (elements(1)), collec
    Else
        dict(elements(1)).Add elements(0)
    End If
```

will store the time stamps associated with each userID.

If you assume that every user has an `IN`, and that there is an `OUT` for every `IN` then you can just go through sequentially. But you'd be better off checking, and also storing the event type with the time, so as to avoid errors.  Or storing the ts's in pairs (arrays) with the first element being IN and the second being OUT.  pre-Sorting the data by USER ID, and then by TS, might be helpful as you would only need to check the line below for equality of user id, and an OUT event (after each IN event).

### Edit2

I think the following will do what you want.
Although not necessary, I am using a class module as it makes documentation and modifications much simpler.

Here is the algorithm:

- Read the entire CSV file into a variant array

  - Split on the newline character
- Write to a temporary worksheet

  - sort on User ID, then on Time
  - This should result in sequential IN/OUT if both exist
  - Could write a VBA sort routine, but I don't happen to have a fast, "stable" one, and the Excel sorting is pretty flexible, as well as being stable and fast.
- With the sorted order, create a dictionary where the Key is a generated sequential number, and the item is a class object consisting of the User ID, TS IN and TS OUT

  - have to check the next line to be sure there is an OUT that matches the IN for that user, otherwise, don't add it to the dictionary.
- Create results worksheets -  one for all the data, and one for each month.
- Write the results to the results worksheet. Include a column for the monthIN (see the Class module for that calculation)
- Filter the results to populate the Months worksheets

### Class Module

```
'**RENAME**:  cUser
Option Explicit
Private puserID As String
Private ptmIN As Long
Private ptmOUT As Long
Public Property Get userID() As String
    userID = puserID
End Property
Public Property Let userID(value As String)
    puserID = value
End Property

Public Property Get tmIN()
    If ptmIN = 0 Then
        tmIN = ""
    Else
        tmIN = ptmIN
    End If
End Property
Public Property Let tmIN(value)
    ptmIN = value
End Property

Public Property Get tmOUT()
    If ptmOUT = 0 Then
        tmOUT = ""
    Else
        tmOUT = ptmOUT
    End If
End Property
Public Property Let tmOUT(value)
    ptmOUT = value
End Property

Public Property Get monthIN() As Long
    monthIN = Month(DateAdd("s", Me.tmIN, DateSerial(1970, 1, 1)))
End Property

Public Property Get monthOUT() As Long
    monthOUT = Month(DateAdd("s", Me.tmOUT, DateSerial(1970, 1, 1)))
End Property
```

### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
Sub inOUT()
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, TS As TextStream
    Dim dU As Dictionary, cU As cUser
    Dim fn As Variant
    Dim vSrc, vRes, V
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, r As Range
    Dim wsRes As Worksheet, wsMonth(1 To 12) As Worksheet, rMonth As Range
    Dim eventID As Long

'Read file
fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text File (*.txt;*.csv), *.txt;*.csv")
If fn = False Then Exit Sub

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(fn, ForReading, False, TristateUseDefault)
vSrc = Split(TS.ReadAll, vbNewLine) ' line = one array element

'write to temp worksheet
'split text to columns
'sort by user id, then by time
'read back into array
'delete the temp worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
Set r = ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vSrc) + 1)
r = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vSrc)
r.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, textqualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, consecutivedelimiter:=True, _
         Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False

Set r = r.CurrentRegion

r.Sort key1:=r.Columns(2), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=r.Columns(1), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False
vSrc = r

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'collect into dictionary
'assign sequential event ID's
'new event ID for every `IN` event
'same event ID if Next line is an  `OUT` and `user id` matches

eventID = 0
Set dU = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1) 'skip header line
If IsNumeric(vSrc(I, 1)) Then
    eventID = eventID + 1
    Set cU = New cUser
    With cU
        .userID = vSrc(I, 2)
        If vSrc(I, 3) = "IN" Then .tmIN = vSrc(I, 1)

        If vSrc(I + 1, 3) = "OUT" And vSrc(I + 1, 2) = .userID Then
            .tmOUT = vSrc(I + 1, 1)
            I = I + 1

            'add to dictionary
            dU.Add Key:=eventID, Item:=cU
        End If
    End With
End If
Next I

'create results array
ReDim vRes(0 To dU.Count, 1 To 5)

'headers
    vRes(0, 1) = "Event ID"
    vRes(0, 2) = "User ID"
    vRes(0, 3) = "TS IN"
    vRes(0, 4) = "TS OUT"
    vRes(0, 5) = "Month IN"

'Data
    I = 0
    For Each V In dU.Keys
        I = I + 1
        Set cU = dU(V)
        With cU
            If (.tmOUT - .tmIN) < (86400 * 48) And _
                .monthIN = .monthOUT Then
                vRes(I, 1) = V
                vRes(I, 2) = .userID
                vRes(I, 3) = .tmIN
                vRes(I, 4) = .tmOUT
                vRes(I, 5) = .monthIN
            End If
        End With
    Next V

'set results worksheets
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
    For J = 1 To 12
    Set wsMonth(J) = Worksheets(MonthName(J))
        If Err.Number = 9 Then
            Set wsMonth(J) = Worksheets.Add
            wsMonth(J).Name = MonthName(J)
        End If
        wsMonth(J).Cells.Clear
    Next J
    Set wsRes = Worksheets("Results")
        If Err.Number = 9 Then
            Set wsRes = Worksheets.Add
            wsRes.Name = "Results"
        End If
On Error GoTo 0

'write and sort all the results
Set r = wsRes.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With r
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .value = vRes
    .Range(.Columns(3), .Columns(4)).NumberFormat = "#"
    .Sort key1:=r.Columns(3), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    .Style = "Output"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Filter to the month sheets
    For J = 1 To 12
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=J
        .Resize(columnsize:=4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsMonth(J).Cells(1, 1)
        wsMonth(J).UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next J
End With

r.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Here are the results on the `January` worksheet:

[image]

For as long as it is available, an excellent reference for basic information about classes can be found at the late Chip Pearson's website page [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191914/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-rosenfeld-how-to-store-and-sort-data-from-a-csv-file).