# Trying to overcome VBA's "Procedure too large" error by using Collection or Dictionary

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm writing an acronym generator and have about 5,000 known terms I'd like to add to a collection or dictionary object. Unfortunately VBA limits how many lines of code can appear in a single subroutine, so I receive an error if I try to add the terms individually. Is there a way to add numerous 2-D values to a collection or dictionary using a single line of code?

Thx in advance

I tried adding the 2-D values using individual lines of code and received a compile error: "Procedure too large."

Comment: Why not store the terms in a separate file?

Comment: See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670752/how-to-store-and-sort-data-from-a-csv-file-into-a-dictionary-vba or https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141276/load-txt-to-scripting-dictionary

Comment: Hi BigBen, that was always an option, but because I want to distribute this to fellow editors, want to keep it self contained. Unless someone comes up with a code-based solution, I'll add the 5,000 terms to the end of my word document, and have the code process them from there ... Thx

Comment: If you all have access to some shared online document store you could load the list from there...

Comment: I find your approach fanisincating, [highly illogical](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5O7L9oTsxk&ab_channel=DeadHippieMan).  It's only logical to separate the data from the code where it becomes data driven and can update the acronym list without effecting the code. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can load your data to a Collection with a single line of code (and with a Module of supporting code) by storing your acronym data in the 'custom XML' within the Document. In summary, the steps are:

1. Add the 'DataStore' code that supports loading and retrieving the data into / from the custom XML
2. Temporarily, add a table with your terms and acronyms
3. Run the LoadData method in the 'DataStore' code
4. Delete the table
5. Use the XML data

In detail

1. Add the 'DataStore' code that supports loading and retrieving the data into / from the custom XML

Add a standard Module called 'DataStore' (you can rename it later) and add the following code to it. The code is commented for an explanation.

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module
    
Private Const msDATA_NAME As String = "MyHiddenData"
Private Const msITEM As String = "Item"
Private Const msNAME As String = "Name"
Private Const msVALUE As String = "Value"


'***************************************
'* PROCEDURES FOR THE DEVELOPER TO RUN *
'***************************************

' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Load data to this Document's custom XML (ie a 'CustomXMLPart')
' 1. In this Document, create a 2-column Table with the 'key' in the first column and the 'value' in the second column
' 2. Put the cursor in the Table
' 3. Run this method ... fix any errors with the data in the Table unless you see "Successfully loaded data ..."
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub LoadData()
    Dim sXML As String, tbl As Table
    sXML = "<" & msDATA_NAME & ">" & vbNewLine
    Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)
    
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, sValue As String
    For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        sKey = SwapSpecials(tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, True)
        sValue = SwapSpecials(tbl.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text, True)
        sXML = sXML & "    <" & msITEM & " " & msNAME & "=""" & sKey & """ " & msVALUE & "=""" & sValue & """/>" & vbNewLine
    Next i
    sXML = sXML & "</" & msDATA_NAME & ">" & vbNewLine
    
    DeleteExisting
    ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts.Add sXML
    
    MsgBox "Successfully loaded data as CustomXMLPart '" & msDATA_NAME & "'"
End Sub


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: If you want to delete any custom XML data, run this method and select which CustomXMLPart(s) to delete
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub DeleteCustomXMLParts()
    Dim cxp As CustomXMLPart, i As Long, bFound As Boolean
    For i = ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set cxp = ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts(i)
        If Not cxp.BuiltIn Then
            bFound = True
            If MsgBox("Do you want to delete CustomXMLPart '" & cxp.DocumentElement.BaseName & "'?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                cxp.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Not bFound Then
        MsgBox "Found no CustomXMLParts to delete"
    End If
End Sub


'***********************************************************
'* PUBLIC PROCEDURES TO BE CALLED BY CODE IN OTHER MODULES *
'***********************************************************


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get all of the load data as a Collection
' Parameter outsColl (Collection): If successful, will be updated with the data, otherwise will be an empty Collection
' Returns (Boolean): True if successful, False otherwise
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function TryGetAllData(ByRef outsColl As Collection) As Boolean
    Dim cxp As CustomXMLPart
    Set outsColl = New Collection
    If TryGetPart(msDATA_NAME, cxp) Then
        Dim cxn As CustomXMLNode
        For Each cxn In cxp.SelectNodes("/" & msDATA_NAME & "/*")
            outsColl.Add SwapSpecials(GetAttributeValue(cxn, msVALUE), False), SwapSpecials(GetAttributeValue(cxn, msNAME), False)
        Next cxn
        TryGetAllData = True
    End If
End Function


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get the value for a given key
' Parameter sKey (String): The key
' Parameter outsValue (String): If successful, will be updated with the value associated with the key, otherwise an
'     empty String
' Returns (Boolean): True if successful, False otherwise
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function TryGetData(sKey As String, ByRef outsValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim cxp As CustomXMLPart
    If TryGetPart(msDATA_NAME, cxp) Then
        TryGetData = TryGetNodeText(cxp, sKey, outsValue)
    End If
End Function



'*****************************
'* PRIVATE HELPER PROCEDURES *
'*****************************


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Delete the loaded XML data, if present
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub DeleteExisting()
    Dim cxp As CustomXMLPart, i As Long
    For i = ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set cxp = ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts(i)
        If Not cxp.BuiltIn Then
            If cxp.DocumentElement.BaseName = msDATA_NAME Then
                cxp.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get a CustomXMLPart
' Parameter sPartName (String): The name of the CustomXMLPart
' Parameter outCxp (CustomXMLPart): If successful, will be updated with the CustomXMLPart object, otherwise Nothing
' Returns (Boolean): True if successful, False otherwise
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function TryGetPart(sPartName As String, ByRef outCxp As CustomXMLPart) As Boolean
    Dim cxp As CustomXMLPart
    For Each cxp In ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts
        If cxp.DocumentElement.BaseName = sPartName Then
            Set outCxp = cxp
            TryGetPart = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cxp
End Function


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get the text of a CustomXMLNode
' Parameter cxp (CustomXMLPart): The CustomXMLPart that the CustomXMLNode is within
' Parameter sNodeName (String): The name of the CustomXMLNode
' Parameter outsText (String): If successful, will be updated with the text of the CustomXMLNode, otherwise an empty
'     String
' Returns (Boolean): True if successful, False otherwise
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function TryGetNodeText(cxp As CustomXMLPart, sNodeName As String, ByRef outsText As String) As Boolean
    Dim sXPath As String
    If InStr(1, sNodeName, "'") = 0 Then
        sXPath = "//" & msITEM & "[@" & msNAME & "='" & sNodeName & "']"
    Else
        ' use the XPath 'concat' function to work around the fact that the path is both enclosed in, and contains,
        ' apostrophes
        Dim sConcat As String
        sConcat = "concat('" & Join(Split(sNodeName, "'"), "', ""'"", '") & "')"
        sXPath = "//" & msITEM & "[@" & msNAME & "=" & sConcat & "]"
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo errExit
    outsText = GetAttributeValue(cxp.SelectSingleNode(sXPath), msVALUE)
    TryGetNodeText = True
    Exit Function
errExit:
End Function


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Swap 'special characters'
' Parameter sText (String): The input String
' Parameter bLoading (Boolean): If True, the end-of-cell characters for Word Tables are removed and characters that are
'     'special' in XML are escaped; if False, escaped characters are replaced with the 'original' character
' Returns (String): The 'swapped' String
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function SwapSpecials(sText As String, bLoading As Boolean) As String
    If bLoading Then
        SwapSpecials = Replace(sText, Chr$(13) & Chr$(7), vbNullString)
        SwapSpecials = Replace(SwapSpecials, "&", "&amp;")
        SwapSpecials = Replace(SwapSpecials, """", "&quot;")
        SwapSpecials = Replace(SwapSpecials, "'", "&apos;")
        SwapSpecials = Replace(SwapSpecials, "<", "&lt;")
        SwapSpecials = Replace(SwapSpecials, ">", "&gt;")
    Else
        SwapSpecials = Replace(sText, "&gt;", ">")
        SwapSpecials = Replace(SwapSpecials, "&lt;", "<")
        SwapSpecials = Replace(SwapSpecials, "&apos;", "'")
        SwapSpecials = Replace(SwapSpecials, "&quot;", """")
        SwapSpecials = Replace(SwapSpecials, "&amp;", "&")
    End If
End Function


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get the value of an Attribute from a CustomXMLNode
' Parameter cxn (CustomXMLNode): The CustomXMLNode
' Parameter sAttrName (String): The name of the Attribute
' Returns (String): The value of the Attrubute
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function GetAttributeValue(cxn As CustomXMLNode, sAttrName As String) As String
    Dim attr As CustomXMLNode
    For Each attr In cxn.Attributes
        If attr.BaseName = sAttrName Then
            GetAttributeValue = attr.Text
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next attr
End Function
```

2. Temporarily, add a table with your terms and acronyms

In the same document, add a 2-column Table where the first column contains the 'key' (in your case this is the term) and the second column contains the value (in your case this is the acronym). As this is going to be loaded into a Collection then the each 'key' must be unique (not case sensitive ie so two keys called "key" and "Key" are not allowed)

3. Run the LoadData method in the 'DataStore' code

Put the cursor / caret into the Table and run `DataStore.LoadData`, ensure you see the "Successfully loaded data ..." message (otherwise fix any reported problems).

4. Delete the table

You might want to run the below test methods first, however, you can now delete the table and save your document ... it now has the XML stored within it. If you need to update the terms / acronyms again in the future, you can just temporarily add a table, run `DataStore.LoadData` then delete the Table.

5. Use the XML data

The single line being

```
DataStore.TryGetAllData collOfAcronyms
```

... where `collOfAcronyms` is your Collection, though in reality you will want to use this in an `If` statement as follows in the `TestAll` test method.

The test methods are (`TestAll` is an example of loading all terms/acronyms into a single Collection; `TestIndividual` is an example of loading a single acronym from a term on-the-fly):

```
Sub TestAll()
    Dim collOfAcronyms As Collection
    If DataStore.TryGetAllData(collOfAcronyms) Then
        Dim tbl As Table, i As Long, sText As String
        Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)
        For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
            sText = Replace(tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, Chr$(13) & Chr$(7), vbNullString)
            Debug.Print Now, "'" & sText & "' = '" & collOfAcronyms.Item(sText) & "'"
        Next i
    Else
        Debug.Print Now, "Failed"
    End If
End Sub


Sub TestIndividual()
    Dim tbl As Table, i As Long, sText As String
    Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)
    Dim sAcronym As String
    For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        sText = Replace(tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, Chr$(13) & Chr$(7), vbNullString)
        If DataStore.TryGetData(sText, sAcronym) Then
            Debug.Print Now, "'" & sText & "' = '" & sAcronym & "'"
        Else
            Debug.Print Now, "'" & sText & "' ... failed"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

... obviously these will only work while the Table is still in the document, normal usage will be, for the Collection ... load the data

```
Dim collOfAcronyms As Collection
If DataStore.TryGetAllData(collOfAcronyms) Then
    ' successfully got all of the acronyms ... use them
Else
    ' failed to get the acronyms
End If
```

... then use the Collection as you would any other eg

```
sAcronym = collOfAcronyms.Item(sTerm)
```

And usage to get individual acronyms (ie without loading all terms and acronyms into a Collection first) will be eg

```
If DataStore.TryGetData(sTerm, sAcronym) Then
    ' successfully got the acronym ... use it
Else
    ' failed to get the acronym (no such term?)
End If
```

Comment: Sounds promising John, love learning new techniques. Wanted to thank you for your thorough response, and let you know I'll be giving it a try as soon as I can find some time. Regards, Dave Gaines

Comment: Hi John, just wanted to let you know your code worked like a champ. I draw potential meanings from the document itself, and wanted to add potential meanings from my massive, 2-column, acronym table which loaded successfully into a collection using your code. Wanted to thank you again for your thorough and excellent explanation, though I'll admit I still don't understand it all quite yet.

Comment: Added the following lines to add potential meanings from the collection:

    'the following 3 lines check for the acronym in the embedded xml collection, and adds suggested meaning to column 2 if found
    On Error Resume Next
        oTable.Cell(Row, 2).Range.Text = Replace(Left(oTable.Cell(Row, 2).Range.Text, Len(oTable.Cell(Row, 2).Range.Text) - 2) & vbCr & collOfAcronyms.Item(Left(oTable.Cell(Row, 1).Range.Text, Len(oTable.Cell(Row, 1).Range.Text) - 2)), "; ", vbCr)
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Comment: Glad it worked! If you are happy with the answer then please click on the tick/check mark next to it to let others know your question has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what MS specify about a module capacity:

> There is no specific limit on the number of lines in a module. The total size of a code module should not exceed 64K (65536 characters) - beyond that, code will become unstable.

Verbosely:

How many lines of code can one module in VBA editor contain ... (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-many-lines-of-code-can-one-module-in-vba/7352d440-4181-4a3d-b685-be50119eed87)

This result that capacity is not depending on the arrays dictionaries or other objects methods of how they are filled, but only the code text length, with which you want to fulfill the job.

BigBen suggestion is a simple way to get the result you need. The external file than  can be loaded with one of the filereader methods to a suitable object.

**A workaround**

Define a **global** variable which will be the storage of the large data.

Start to fill the data in **Module1**. At the end of the window capacity
call another Sub from another module e.g. **Module2** and continue the fill operation on that program segment. And so on.

```
Public Store as Dictionary

Public Sub FillCode1()

'Here are the instructions to fill Store object with the data part1.

FillCode2

End Sub 'FillCode1
```

In a new Module

```
Public Sub FillCode2()

'Here are the instructions to fill Store object with the data part2.

FillCode3

End Sub 'FillCode2
```

In a new Module

```
Public Sub FillCode3()

' The end of the fill instructions with data part3 and the processing code.

End Sub
```