# Find Highest Value based On Two Criteria, then Write to Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large csv/Excel invoice (UPS - not sure if that will matter). I validate and assign missing cost centers every week, using VBA to automate this process.

Usually it is no more complicated than, if x is this cell, then use y cost center.

Here is the problem:

We use a consolidated invoice which contains many different accounts. Sometimes the account is charged a service fee. If so, that service fee is applied to the cost center under the account which had the highest amount of charges.

Here is a stripped-down example.

We start with:
[image: Start]

Because `D8` says “Service Fee” I need `B8` to equal the cost center with the highest amount of charges. In the case of Account1, CostCenter1 has the most charges at $17.00. For Account2, it will be CostCenter3.

The final product should look like:
[image: End]

I would show some code but I am at a loss of where to start.

Comment: There are various ways you can do this. You can use Arrays to save the data and do a quick Sum to check which cost center to allocate, or you could use a pivot table, or you could just use loops to sum the amount whenever you hit the "Service Fee" in your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a user-defined function that returns the CostCenter you need:

```
Public Function MaxCC()

Dim strAcc As String, strCC As String, dblChg As Double, lastrow As Long

strAcc = Application.Caller.Offset(, -1).Value2
lastrow = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim dictCC As New Scripting.Dictionary

Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Application.Caller.Worksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value2 = strAcc Then
        If i <> Application.Caller.Row Then strCC = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value2
        dblChg = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Cells(i, 3).Value2

        If Not dictCC.Exists(strCC) Then dictCC.Add strCC, 0

        dictCC(strCC) = dictCC(strCC) + dblChg
    End If
Next i

Dim strMaxCC As String, dblMaxCC As Double, varKey As Variant
dblMaxCC = 0
For Each varKey In dictCC.Keys
    If dictCC(varKey) > dblMaxCC Then
        strMaxCC = CStr(varKey)
        dblMaxCC = dictCC(varKey)
    End If
Next varKey

MaxCC = strMaxCC

End Function
```

This function uses a dictionary, just be sure to reference `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/915333/9173379).

You will be able to enter `=MaxCC()` as a formula into the empty cells you need filled and it will provide you with the correct CostCenter. Let me know if this works for you and if you have follow-up questions.

Comment: Yes perfect simple solution.  Dictionarys are great. I use them often. But based on the header of the question i am not that sure if he get it :) Anyhow he will learn something new :)

Comment: This function works in my example and points me in the direction I want to go. I thought dictionaries would be involved but I didn't have enough experience to know. As @ThomasLudewig stated, I don't really get it but I am happy to dissect this and learn over the next couple days. Much appreciated

Comment: @IanWebster Feel free to ask for clarification on or explanation of specific parts if you need anything, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

For a formula in cell application,

```
=INDEX(A:C,MATCH(MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,"="& A8,C:C,"<>"&C8),C:C),2)
```

Just replace A8/C8 with the row it is being put into, or paste it into B8, and then copy/paste the cell into other rows. it's a quick fix and no programming, just using the built-in functionality of Excel.

[image]

Comment: I've done that. Ran into issues when I got handed a data set of over 100,000 values which needed to be parsed and referenced against each other. The problem with using public function x(a as variant, b as long, ... z as string) as variant is the processing time it takes for excel in trying to calculate the amount going on. It depends on the complexity of what you want to do, and if you can reasonably pull out the meaning of a function. For this, it works and it's reasonably readable.

Comment: Depends on taste. I often do not use my programs for quite a while and then the mentioned fun part follows. 100.000 VBA values are not a problem. If that causes performmance issues then i would say you has a problem in the algorithm itselv, Such datamasses i would put in head of a module and update they on needs. To parse them on every excel calculation step is for sure not a good idea.  In one of my acad programs ive git 8.000.000 coordinates in 3d. To find the next by coordinate takes 8 ms. Based on a clever algorithm (octree) VBA is  not the performance  brake. if nothing helps -> c++ dll.

Comment: It was more a problem in what I was requested to do, than a problem with the algorithms. It took 36 custom functions and turning Excel into a makeshift database for modeling changes across 16 different groups over 29 different projects, over a projected period of 2 years, in allowing any changes made in the weekly scheduling to be changed - whether it was in where the number of hours per week, or the actual timing of the projects - and propagate out for cost, manpower, and funding required at any point, from a collection of sheets that were hastily thrown together. I told them it would be slow

Comment: Are you totally sure that Excel was the tool of choice in that case ? I would use a server based database and just maybee Excel as some kind of Frontend. I do not understand why a lot of people thing a simple table sheet can be as good as a database. And later they start wondering obout the results. Excel is nice to collect some table datas like a color book.Have a look here http://www.wampserver.com/en/ You can collect your datas central, connect with  whatever ODBC native connectors etc . And the beast is free of charge.

Comment: I agree that Excel would Not have been my tool of choice for the matter; they actually have a Quick Base(QB) account with open App slots and bandwidth that would have functioned better for it. BUT... management said no to using QB as their "dedicated" devs (I was new-hire 'Data Analyst', even though I'm certified as an Expert Developer for QB) "Didn't have time". So, instead they had me program out a massive Excel sheet to do it, slowly. Got shifted then to the Next project, which will probably be handed the same as the last.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function max2(arr,i) as double
  dim max as double 
  max=arr(i,0);
  for j=0 to ubound(arr,2)
    if arr(i,j)>max then max=arr(i,j)
   next
    max2=max
 end sub 

 sub test

  'build some kind of array structure for your pricing mess

  dim cc() as double
  redim cc(2,3)


   'just fill the structure somehow
   cc(0,0)=1'cc=cost center
   cc(0,1)=2
   cc(0,2)=3

   cc(1,0)=5
   cc(1,1)=1
   cc(1,2)=7

   'get the maximum profit to be able to buy a new Porsche      

  debug.print max2(cc,0)  

  debug.print max2(cc,1)

 'if we need a Ferrari

  result=max2(cc,0)  
  if max2(cc,1) > result then result =max2(cc,1)

  ' or just add a modified max sub with just one dimension
  'or fill a virtual cost center array with the results so far... and run the 
  'max2 fucntion on that  

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a class, I used late binding on the dictionaries, if you want early binding add the reference and `set variable = New Dictionary`

Class Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private pCenterdict As Object

Public Sub Load_Data(center As String, cost As Double)
    If Not pCenterdict.Exists(center) Then
        pCenterdict.Add center, cost
    Else
        pCenterdict(center) = pCenterdict(center) + cost
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub initialize()
    Set pCenterdict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Public Function return_highest() As String
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim highestkey As String
    Dim highestval As Double

    highestval = 0
    For Each key In pCenterdict.Keys()
        If pCenterdict(key) > highestval Then
            highestval = pCenterdict(key)
            highestkey = key
        End If
    Next key
    return_highest = highestkey
End Function
```

Main code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Dim clsdict As Object
    Dim clsobj As Object

    Set clsdict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change this to whatever the sheet name is
    lr = .Cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    For i = 2 To lr
        If Not .Cells(i, 4).value = "Service Fee" Then
            If Not clsdict.Exists(.Cells(i, 1).value) Then
                Set clsobj = New Cls_SO 'Create instance, If you name your class something else change this to New YourClassNameHere
                clsobj.initialize 'Create Dictionary
                clsobj.Load_Data .Cells(i, 2).value, .Cells(i, 3).value 'Load Values
                clsdict.Add .Cells(i, 1).value, clsobj
            Else
                clsdict(.Cells(i, 1).value).Load_Data .Cells(i, 2).value, .Cells(i, 3).value 'Load Values
            End If
        Else
            .Cells(i, 2).value = clsdict(.Cells(i, 1).value).return_highest 'Get Highest
        End If
    Next
    End With



End Sub
```