# Search an array and return count?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a large dataset and I'm using VBA to analyse the data. I'm using a For loop.

As the data contains parts for a Bill of Materials, its highly likely that duplicates exist. Once the data has been analysed, I'd like to filter the errors out, but I  want to exclude duplicates.

On a previous version of the code "WorksheetFunction.CountIf" was used to count the part number in the current row from all the previous rows. If the count = 1 then the value is unique (at this point) and a "U" is entered in a column, if the count is greater than 1 then the value is a duplicate and "D" is entered into the column.

Once all data is analysed, I can filter by the errors and "U" values and I have my a list without duplicates.

However, with a dataset of ~100,000 rows, "WorksheetFunction.CountIf" is very slow...

My new code makes use of an array (due to answers from a previous question asked here) and I'm not sure how to search the from the top of the array to the current row number (in my case this is the 'counter')

```
For Counter 1 to UBound(InputArr)
```

Is there a way to search certain columns of an array from the top (UBound) to a row number and count?

Maybe I'm asking too much

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many columns are in the array? Thought of using a collection or a dictionary to get unique values?

Comment: You could use either a `Dictionary`, `Collection`, or `ArrayList` to avoid entering the duplicates in the first place; or, after the table is on the worksheet, you could use the `Range.RemoveDuplicates` method to remove them.  If you need the Count for some other reason, I would use the `Dictionary` object.

Comment: The array consists of 34 columns. Unfortunately I can't just remove duplicates.

Comment: If you don't want to **remove** the duplicates, then just **test** for it using one of the objects I mentioned, and mark it in your array with `U` or a `D` before you write the array back to the worksheet.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure) for a basic explanation about dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to search certain columns of an array from the top (UBound) to a row number and count?

Absolutely!

Knowing:

- the array
- the column number of the array
- the value we want to search for in the column

We can:

1. Loop through the rows of the array
2. Get the value in the column we care about
3. Compare that to the value we're searching for
4. Increment a counter each time we find a match

```
Option Explicit

Private Function CountValuesInColumn(arr As Variant, column As Long, searchValue As Variant) As Long

    Dim row As Long, count As Long
    For row = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    
        If arr(row, column) = searchValue Then
            
            count = count + 1
            
        End If
    
    Next row
    
    CountValuesInColumn = count

End Function
```

Here's a test of the function:

```
Private Sub Test()

    Dim testArray(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As Variant
    testArray(1, 1) = "a"
    testArray(2, 1) = "b"
    testArray(3, 1) = "a"
    testArray(4, 1) = "b"
    
    testArray(1, 2) = "a"
    testArray(2, 2) = "b"
    testArray(3, 2) = "c"
    testArray(4, 2) = "b"
    
    ' How many "a" values are in column 1?
    Dim result As Long
    result = CountValuesInColumn(testArray, 1, "a") '2
    
    ' How many "a" values are in column 2?
    result = CountValuesInColumn(testArray, 2, "a") '1
    
    ' How many "d" values are in column 1?
    result = CountValuesInColumn(testArray, 1, "d") '0

End Sub
```

In my example, I loop through the entire array.  If you want to only loop through a number of rows, you will replace `Ubound(arr,1)` with whatever you want the upper limit to be.  It would probably need to be another parameter of the `CountValuesInColumn` function.  I'll leave those modifications to you.